# How do I read CSV data into a record array in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, genfromtxt

Is there a direct way to import the contents of a CSV file into a record array, just like how R's `read.table()`, `read.delim()`, and `read.csv()` import data into R dataframes?

Or should I use [`csv.reader()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859404/reading-csv-files-in-scipy-numpy-in-python) and then apply `numpy.core.records.fromrecords()`?

Answer (score 872, accepted):

Use [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) by setting the `delimiter` kwarg to a comma:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('my_file.csv', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: What if you want something of different types? Like strings and ints?

Comment: @CGTheLegend np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv',delimiter=',',dtype=None)

Comment: [numpy.loadtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) worked pretty well for me too

Comment: I tried this but I am only getting `nan` values, why? Also with loadtxt, I am getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 155: ordinal not in range(128)`. I have umlauts such as ä and ö in the input data.

Comment: @hhh try adding `encoding="utf8"` argument. Python is one of the few modern software pieces that frequently causes text encoding problems, which feel as things from the past.

Comment: use skip_header=1 to skip the first line if you're reading from a file with a header. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt

Comment: The problem with this method is that if you have only one row of data, then instead of reading a column list with one item you will get the item directly. Therefore, this solution is not generally usable, but needs to used differently based on the number of the records in the CSV file.

Comment: @kolen It is a windows problem. On linux encoding='utf8' is by default for quite a long time with the majority of programs, including python.

Answer (score 244):

Use [`pandas.read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', sep=',', header=None)
print(df.values)
```

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 4. ,  5.5,  6. ]])
```

This gives a pandas [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#dataframe) which provides [many useful data manipulation functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11077215/1461850) which are not directly available with numpy record arrays.

> `DataFrame` is a 2-dimensional labeled data structure with columns of
> potentially different types. You can think of it like a spreadsheet or
> SQL table...

---

I would also recommend [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). However, since the question asks for a [record array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html), as opposed to a normal array, the `dtype=None` parameter needs to be added to the `genfromtxt` call:

```
import numpy as np
np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',')
```

For the following `'myfile.csv'`:

```
1.0, 2, 3
4, 5.5, 6
```

the code above gives an array:

```
array([[ 1. ,  2. ,  3. ],
       [ 4. ,  5.5,  6. ]])
```

and

```
np.genfromtxt('myfile.csv', delimiter=',', dtype=None)
```

gives a record array:

```
array([(1.0, 2.0, 3), (4.0, 5.5, 6)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

This has the advantage that files with [multiple data types (including strings) can be easily imported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15481761).

Comment: read_csv works with commas inside quotes. Recommend this over genfromtxt

Comment: use header=0 to skip the first line in the values, if your file has a 1-line header

Comment: Bear in mind that this creates a 2d array: e.g. `(1000, 1)`. `np.genfromtxt` does not do that: e.g. `(1000,)`.

Comment: The OP is asking for Numpy arrays, not about Pandas Dataframe objects.

Comment: @JoséL.Patiño  The second part of the question deals with the request for a [Numpy record array](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html). The first part of the answer shows `df.values` which gives a [Numpy representation of the DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html); a convenient method imho.

Answer (score 94):

I tried it :

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
genfromtxt(fname = dest_file, dtype = (<whatever options>))
```

versus :

```
import csv
import numpy as np
with open(dest_file,'r') as dest_f:
    data_iter = csv.reader(dest_f,
                           delimiter = delimiter,
                           quotechar = '"')
    data = [data for data in data_iter]
data_array = np.asarray(data, dtype = <whatever options>)
```

on 4.6 million rows with about 70 columns and found that the NumPy path took 2 min 16 secs and the csv-list comprehension method took 13 seconds.

I would recommend the csv-list comprehension method as it is most likely relies on pre-compiled libraries and not the interpreter as much as NumPy. I suspect the pandas method would have similar interpreter overhead.

Comment: I tested code similar to this with a csv file containing 2.6 million rows and 8 columns. numpy.recfromcsv() took about 45 seconds, np.asarray(list(csv.reader())) took about 7 seconds, and pandas.read_csv() took about 2 seconds (!). (The file had recently been read from disk in all cases, so it was already in the operating system's file cache.) I think I'll go with pandas.

Comment: I just noticed there are some notes about the design of pandas' fast csv parser at http://wesmckinney.com/blog/a-new-high-performance-memory-efficient-file-parser-engine-for-pandas/ . The author takes speed and memory requirements pretty seriously. It's also possible to use as_recarray=True to get the result directly as a Python record array rather than a pandas dataframe.

Answer (score 70):

You can also try [`recfromcsv()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html#numpy.genfromtxt) which can guess data types and return a properly formatted record array.

Comment: If you want to maintain ordering / column names in the CSV, you can use the following invocation: `numpy.recfromcsv(fname, delimiter=',', filling_values=numpy.nan, case_sensitive=True, deletechars='', replace_space=' ')`
The key arguments are the last three.

Answer (score 26):

As I tried both ways using NumPy and Pandas, using pandas has a lot of advantages:

- Faster
- Less CPU usage
- 1/3 RAM usage compared to NumPy genfromtxt

This is my test code:

```
$ for f in test_pandas.py test_numpy_csv.py ; do  /usr/bin/time python $f; done
2.94user 0.41system 0:03.05elapsed 109%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 502068maxresident)k
0inputs+24outputs (0major+107147minor)pagefaults 0swaps

23.29user 0.72system 0:23.72elapsed 101%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1680888maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+416145minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

#### test_numpy_csv.py

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
train = genfromtxt('/home/hvn/me/notebook/train.csv', delimiter=',')
```

#### test_pandas.py

```
from pandas import read_csv
df = read_csv('/home/hvn/me/notebook/train.csv')
```

#### Data file:

```
du -h ~/me/notebook/train.csv
 59M    /home/hvn/me/notebook/train.csv
```

With NumPy and pandas at versions:

```
$ pip freeze | egrep -i 'pandas|numpy'
numpy==1.13.3
pandas==0.20.2
```

Answer (score 10):

Using [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)

A quite simple method. But it requires all the elements being float (int and so on)

```
import numpy as np 
data = np.loadtxt('c:\\1.csv',delimiter=',',skiprows=0)
```

Comment: Also can use this: '''  data2 = np.genfromtxt(''c:\\1.csv', delimiter=',') '''

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code to send CSV file data into an array:

```
import numpy as np
csv = np.genfromtxt('test.csv', delimiter=",")
print(csv)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is the easiest way:

```py
import csv
with open('testfile.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    data = list(csv.reader(csvfile))
```

Now each entry in data is a record, represented as an array. So you have a 2D array. It saved me so much time.

Comment: Why should we have to screw around with Pandas, when these tools have so much less feature bloat?

Answer (score 7):

**This work as a charm...**

```
import csv
with open("data.csv", 'r') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=";"))

import numpy as np
data = np.array(data, dtype=np.float)
```

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest using tables (`pip3 install tables`). You can save your `.csv` file to `.h5` using pandas (`pip3 install pandas`),

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("dataset.csv")
store = pd.HDFStore('dataset.h5')
store['mydata'] = data
store.close()
```

You can then easily, and with less time even for huge amount of data, load your data in a *NumPy array*.

```
import pandas as pd
store = pd.HDFStore('dataset.h5')
data = store['mydata']
store.close()

# Data in NumPy format
data = data.values
```

Answer (score 6):

Available on the newest pandas and numpy version.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=None)

# Discover, visualize, and preprocess data using pandas if needed.

data = data.to_numpy()
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried this:

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as n

closingValue = p.read_csv("<FILENAME>", usecols=[4], dtype=float)
print(closingValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [329]: %time my_data = genfromtxt('one.csv', delimiter=',')
CPU times: user 19.8 s, sys: 4.58 s, total: 24.4 s
Wall time: 24.4 s

In [330]: %time df = pd.read_csv("one.csv", skiprows=20)
CPU times: user 1.06 s, sys: 312 ms, total: 1.38 s
Wall time: 1.38 s
```

Comment: Please edit the question with some more information about your solution.

Answer (score -1):

this is a very simple task, the best way to do this is as follows

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Clients.csv')   #read the file (put 'r' before the path string to address any special characters in the file such as \). Don't forget to put the file name at the end of the path + ".csv"

print(df)`

y = np.array(df)
```

Comment: The OP asked to read directly to `numpy` array. Reading it as a `dataframe` and converting it to `numpy array` requires more storage and time.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But I just gave another possible way of doing the same thing, if the above doesn't work