# Dump a NumPy array into a csv file

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy

How do I dump a 2D NumPy array into a csv file in a human-readable format?

Answer (score 1250, accepted):

[`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) saves an array to a text file.

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

Comment: is this preferred over looping through the array by dimension? I'm guessing so.

Comment: The array is an ndarray. I hope it adds up.

Comment: you can also change the format of each figure with the fmt keyword. default is '%.18e', this can be hard to read, you can use '%.3e' so only 3 decimals are shown.

Comment: Andrea, Yes I used %10.5f. It was pretty convenient.

Comment: Your method works well for numerical data, but it throws an error for `numpy.array` of strings. Could you prescribe a method to save as csv for an `numpy.array` object containing strings?

Comment: What does the scipy documentation mean when it says delimiter is the character or string separating columns? When I use savetxt() it throws everything in the same column. Also, how do we go about saving in .tsv format? Do we use 4 spaces? The scipy documentation doesn't touch on .tsv at all, but .tsv is such a common format, there must be a way. Any thoughts?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac You can specify the format as string as well: `fmt='%s'`

Comment: You can even set different formats for each column, eg. `fmt = '%.4f, %.8f'` to write 4 and 8 decimals in the first and second column, respectively.

Comment: TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')

Comment: Should this answer have `comments=''` to get rid of the weird hash symbol at the start of the column names?

Comment: @EhteshChoudhury Usually when there is a function you can call instead of creating a loop that accomplishes the same thing, the function call is preferred since it makes the code simpler. (If calling the function wouldn't be the preferred method, why would the function in that case exist?)

Comment: This only works when it's a numerical array. If it's an array of object (string), you need third argument `fmt='%s'` to avoid failing with `TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('object') and format specifier ('%.18e')`. Can you update your answer?

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22582992/14919621

Answer (score 235):

Use the `pandas` library's [`DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). It does take some extra memory, but it's very fast and easy to use.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(np_array)
df.to_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

If you don't want a header or index, use:

```
df.to_csv("path/to/file.csv", header=False, index=False)
```

Comment: I find it again and again that the best csv exports are when 'piped' into pandas' to_csv

Comment: Not good. This creates a df and consumes extra memory for nothing

Comment: worked like charm, it's very fast - tradeoff for extra memory usage. parameters `header=None, index=None` remove header row and index column.

Comment: Works for lists with strings, too.

Comment: The `numpy.savetxt` method is great, but it puts a hash symbol at the start of the header line.

Comment: @DaveC : You have to set the `comments` keyword argument to `''`, the `#` will be suppressed.

Comment: `index=False` not `index=None`, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: @maxbellec  It gives,     ValueError: Must pass 2-d input

Comment: @AbhilashSinghChauhan well yes, csv data is 2 dimensionnal (row and columns)

Comment: @maxbellec I know that CSV data is 2D data, but while reading raster as numpy dataset, it additionally add the layer count and dataset become 3-D, even if the raster dataset has single layer, it still shows data as (count, height, width) where count = 1, how to export that data to .CSV or .txt file?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56101795) for why this may be helpful: You can set the decimal separator in pandas on export.

Comment: In case it's not a numpy array but a list with lists (a Matrix ) `m1 = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]`, this answer works like a charm as well!

Answer (score 60):

[`tofile`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) is a convenient function to do this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
a.tofile('foo.csv',sep=',',format='%10.5f')
```

The man page has some useful notes:

> This is a convenience function for quick storage of array data.
>   Information on endianness and precision is lost, so this method is not
>   a good choice for files intended to archive data or transport data
>   between machines with different endianness. Some of these problems can
>   be overcome by outputting the data as text files, at the expense of
>   speed and file size.

Note. This function does not produce multi-line csv files, it saves everything to one line.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not produce a csv file, but puts everything on a single line.

Comment: @Peter, good point, thanks, I've updated the answer. For me it does save ok in csv format (albeit limited to one line). Also, it's clear that the asker's intent is to "dump it in human-readable format" - so I think the answer is relevant and useful.

Comment: Actually, np.savetext() provides the newline argument, not np.tofile()

Answer (score 25):

As already discussed, the best way to dump the array into a CSV file is by using `.savetxt(...)`method. However, there are certain things we should know to do it properly.

For example, if you have a numpy array with `dtype = np.int32` as

```
   narr = np.array([[1,2],
                 [3,4],
                 [5,6]], dtype=np.int32)
```

and want to save using `savetxt` as

```
np.savetxt('values.csv', narr, delimiter=",")
```

It will store the data in floating point exponential format as

```
1.000000000000000000e+00,2.000000000000000000e+00
3.000000000000000000e+00,4.000000000000000000e+00
5.000000000000000000e+00,6.000000000000000000e+00
```

You will have to change the formatting by using a parameter called `fmt` as

```
np.savetxt('values.csv', narr, fmt="%d", delimiter=",")
```

to store data in its original format

### Saving Data in Compressed gz format

Also, `savetxt` can be used for storing data in `.gz` compressed format which might be useful while transferring data over network.

We just need to change the extension of the file as `.gz` and numpy will take care of everything automatically

```
np.savetxt('values.gz', narr, fmt="%d", delimiter=",")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The `fmt="%d"` was what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

Writing record arrays as CSV files with headers requires a bit more work.

This example reads from a CSV file (`example.csv`) and writes its contents to another CSV file (`out.csv`).

```
import numpy as np

# Write an example CSV file with headers on first line
with open('example.csv', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write('''\
col1,col2,col3
1,100.1,string1
2,222.2,second string
''')

# Read it as a Numpy record array
ar = np.recfromcsv('example.csv', encoding='ascii')
print(repr(ar))
# rec.array([(1, 100.1, 'string1'), (2, 222.2, 'second string')], 
#           dtype=[('col1', '<i8'), ('col2', '<f8'), ('col3', '<U13')])

# Write as a CSV file with headers on first line
with open('out.csv', 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(','.join(ar.dtype.names) + '\n')
    np.savetxt(fp, ar, '%s', ',')
```

Note that the above example cannot handle values which are strings with commas. To always enclose non-numeric values within quotes, use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) built-in module:

```
import csv

with open('out2.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    writer.writerow(ar.dtype.names)
    writer.writerows(ar.tolist())
```

Comment: This is where pandas again helps. You can do: pd.DataFrame(out, columns=['col1', 'col2']), etc

Comment: Seems so much work comparing to other solutions

Answer (score 11):

To store a NumPy array to a text file, import `savetxt` from the NumPy module

consider your Numpy array name is **train_df**:

```
import numpy as np
np.savetxt('train_df.txt', train_df, fmt='%s')
```

OR

```
from numpy import savetxt
savetxt('train_df.txt', train_df, fmt='%s')
```

Comment: Since you are calling `np.savetext(...`, you don't need the import call `from numpy import savetxt`. If you do import it, you can simply call it as `savetext(...`

Answer (score 8):

I believe you can also accomplish this quite simply as follows:

1. Convert Numpy array into a Pandas dataframe
2. Save as CSV

e.g. #1:

```
    # Libraries to import
    import pandas as pd
    import nump as np

    #N x N numpy array (dimensions dont matter)
    corr_mat    #your numpy array
    my_df = pd.DataFrame(corr_mat)  #converting it to a pandas dataframe
```

e.g. #2:

```
    #save as csv 
    my_df.to_csv('foo.csv', index=False)   # "foo" is the name you want to give
                                           # to csv file. Make sure to add ".csv"
                                           # after whatever name like in the code
```

Comment: No need for a remake, [the original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41096943/774575) is crisp and clear.

Answer (score 5):

**if you want to write in column:**

```
    for x in np.nditer(a.T, order='C'): 
            file.write(str(x))
            file.write("\n")
```

Here 'a' is the name of numpy array and 'file' is the variable to write in a file.

**If you want to write in row:**

```
    writer= csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
    for x in np.nditer(a.T, order='C'): 
            row.append(str(x))
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python we use csv.writer() module to write data into csv files. This module is similar to the csv.reader() module.

```
import csv

person = [['SN', 'Person', 'DOB'],
['1', 'John', '18/1/1997'],
['2', 'Marie','19/2/1998'],
['3', 'Simon','20/3/1999'],
['4', 'Erik', '21/4/2000'],
['5', 'Ana', '22/5/2001']]

csv.register_dialect('myDialect',
delimiter = '|',
quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,
skipinitialspace=True)

with open('dob.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect='myDialect')
    for row in person:
       writer.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

A delimiter is a string used to separate fields. The default value is comma(,).

Comment: This has already been suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41009026/8881141 Please only add new approaches, don't repeat previously published suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

[`numpy.savetxt()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) method is used to save a NumPy array into an output text file, however by default it will make use of scientific notation.

---

If you'd like to avoid this, then you need to specify an appropriate format using `fmt` argument. For example,

```
import numpy as np

np.savetxt('output.csv', arr, delimiter=',', fmt='%f')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save your numpy array (e.g. `your_array = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])`) to one cell, you could convert it first with `your_array.tolist()`.

Then save it the normal way to one cell, with `delimiter=';'`
and the cell in the csv-file will look like this `[[1, 2], [2, 4]]`

Then you could restore your array like this:
`your_array = np.array(ast.literal_eval(cell_string))`

Comment: well that is literally going to destroy all the memory savings for using a numpy array

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with pure python without using any modules.

```
# format as a block of csv text to do whatever you want
csv_rows = ["{},{}".format(i, j) for i, j in array]
csv_text = "\n".join(csv_rows)

# write it to a file
with open('file.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(csv_text)
```

Comment: This uses **a lot of memory**. Prefer looping over each row and format&write it.

Comment: @remram it depends on your data, but yes if it is big it can use a lot of memory

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mentioned, it's important to pass the `fmt=` in order to save a "human-readable" file. In fact, if you pass a separate format for each column, you don't need to pass a delimiter.

```py
arr = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
np.savetxt('out.csv', arr, fmt='%f,%.2f,%.1f')
```

It saves a file whose contents look like:

```
0.000000,1.00,2.0
3.000000,4.00,5.0
6.000000,7.00,8.0
```

Now to read the file from csv, use `np.loadtxt()`:

```py
np.loadtxt('out.csv', delimiter=',')
```

If you want to append to an existing file (as well as create a new file), use a context manager and open a file with `mode='ab'`.

```py
with open('out.csv', 'ab') as f:
    np.savetxt(f, arr, delimiter=',', fmt='%.1f')
```