# printing a two dimensional array in python

Tags: python

I have to print this python code in a 5x5 array the array should look like this :

```
0 1 4 (infinity) 3
1 0 2 (infinity) 4
4 2 0  1         5
(inf)(inf) 1 0   3
3 4 5   3        0
```

can anyone help me print this table? using indices.

```
for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                if A[i][k]+A[k][j]<A[i][j]:
                    A[i][j]=A[i][k]+A[k][j]
```

Comment: Are you purposefully using `j` as your incrementing variable in two nested loops?

Comment: What is the mathematical formula governing the value of each item in the array?

Comment: thank you for catching my mistake. I meant ti use "i"

Comment: The triple loop has nothing to do with the question about printing a 5x5 array. It's uselessly confusing. And "*can anyone help me print this table? **using indices**.*" is trivial. So answers actually answer an unformulated need, which is to have columns aligned, and not specifically using indices (a requirement explicitly added by the OP in a late edit).

Answer (score 78):

There is always the easy way.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.matrix(A))
```

Comment: by far the best answer, let's not reinvent the wheel

Comment: a matrix is not a wheel

Comment: This is not a good answer, if you have a matrix with a large number of float columns, it will totally mess up the display

Comment: How can I get it to print the entire matrix for one that is large, e.g.  size (300, 300)?

Comment: You cant fit a 300x300 matrix on your screen anyways. Try dumping it into a CSV file. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Comment: `numpy.matrix` is now officially deprecated. I'm not sure how else to do this using NumPy though. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Comment: As your link says, just use a `np.ndarray`, e.g. via `np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])`.

Answer (score 71):

A combination of [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and [`str` joins](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) can do the job:

```
inf = float('inf')
A = [[0,1,4,inf,3],
     [1,0,2,inf,4],
     [4,2,0,1,5],
     [inf,inf,1,0,3],
     [3,4,5,3,0]]

print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:4}'.format(item) for item in row]) 
      for row in A]))
```

yields

```
   0   1   4 inf   3
   1   0   2 inf   4
   4   2   0   1   5
 inf inf   1   0   3
   3   4   5   3   0
```

---

Using *for-loops* with indices is usually avoidable in Python, and is not considered "Pythonic" because it is less readable than its Pythonic cousin (see below). However, you could do this:

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        print '{:4}'.format(A[i][j]),
    print
```

The more Pythonic cousin would be:

```
for row in A:
    for val in row:
        print '{:4}'.format(val),
    print
```

However, this uses 30 print statements, whereas my original answer uses just one.

Comment: I need to be able to use the given for loop. Does ANYONE know how to do this? I want to incorporate larger for loops into a program I am working on but I want to use indices.

Comment: inline joining paired with string formatting for item in iterable is so beautifully pythonic. Read as computed, the statement creates a prettily formatted string `'{:4}'.format` `for `[each]` item in` an array [`row`]. Those strings are placed into an array (the statement is surrounded by `[]`), which is then the argument to `''.join`. Then, each of the pretty lines are '\n'.join'ed

Comment: Note one can use generator comprehension instead of list comprehension to save 2 pairs of square brackets:  `print('\n'.join(''.join('{:4}'.format(item) for item in row) for row in matrix))`. 

Also, one can use `print('\n'.join(' '.join('{:3}'.format(item) for item in row) for row in matrix))` if one doesn't want the first column to be prefixed by a space.

Answer (score 6):

```
for i in A:
    print('\t'.join(map(str, i)))
```

Comment: Best answer for arrays of arbitrary objects IMO. I think you can also make it a one-liner too like this:
`print('\n'.join('\t'.join(map(str, row)) for row in A))`

Answer (score 2):

I used numpy to generate the array, but list of lists array should work similarly.

```
import numpy as np
def printArray(args):
    print "\t".join(args)

n = 10

Array = np.zeros(shape=(n,n)).astype('int')

for row in Array:
    printArray([str(x) for x in row])
```

If you want to only print certain indices:

```
import numpy as np
def printArray(args):
    print "\t".join(args)

n = 10

Array = np.zeros(shape=(n,n)).astype('int')

i_indices = [1,2,3]
j_indices = [2,3,4]

for i in i_indices:printArray([str(Array[i][j]) for j in j_indices])
```

Comment: is there a way to use indices?

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best solution for this particular problem (since it doesn't specifically deal with the array structure), but you could also do something like: `def print_join(*args):
    print "\t".join(str(arg) for arg in args)`. Then it would scale to any number of arguments, rather than being fixed at 5.

Answer (score 2):

```
print(mat.__str__())
```

where mat is variable refering to your matrix object

Comment: any reason you call the private method instead of `str(mat)` ?

Answer (score 0):

using indices, for loops and formatting:

```
import numpy as np

def printMatrix(a):
   print "Matrix["+("%d" %a.shape[0])+"]["+("%d" %a.shape[1])+"]"
   rows = a.shape[0]
   cols = a.shape[1]
   for i in range(0,rows):
      for j in range(0,cols):
         print "%6.f" %a[i,j],
      print
   print      


def printMatrixE(a):
   print "Matrix["+("%d" %a.shape[0])+"]["+("%d" %a.shape[1])+"]"
   rows = a.shape[0]
   cols = a.shape[1]
   for i in range(0,rows):
      for j in range(0,cols):
         print("%6.3f" %a[i,j]),
      print
   print      


inf = float('inf')
A = np.array( [[0,1.,4.,inf,3],
     [1,0,2,inf,4],
     [4,2,0,1,5],
     [inf,inf,1,0,3],
     [3,4,5,3,0]])

printMatrix(A)    
printMatrixE(A)
```

which yields the output:

```
Matrix[5][5]
     0      1      4    inf      3
     1      0      2    inf      4
     4      2      0      1      5
   inf    inf      1      0      3
     3      4      5      3      0

Matrix[5][5]
 0.000  1.000  4.000    inf  3.000
 1.000  0.000  2.000    inf  4.000
 4.000  2.000  0.000  1.000  5.000
   inf    inf  1.000  0.000  3.000
 3.000  4.000  5.000  3.000  0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the simple print answer, you can actually customise the print output through the use of the [numpy.set_printoptions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) function.

Prerequisites:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> inf = np.float('inf')
>>> A = np.array([[0,1,4,inf,3],[1,0,2,inf,4],[4,2,0,1,5],[inf,inf,1,0,3],[3,4,5,3,0]])
```

The following option:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(infstr="(infinity)")
```

Results in:

```
>>> print(A)
[[        0.         1.         4. (infinity)         3.]
 [        1.         0.         2. (infinity)         4.]
 [        4.         2.         0.         1.         5.]
 [(infinity) (infinity)         1.         0.         3.]
 [        3.         4.         5.         3.         0.]]
```

The following option:

```
>>> np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': "\t{: 0.0f}\t".format})
```

Results in:

```
>>> print(A)
[[   0       1       4       inf     3  ]
 [   1       0       2       inf     4  ]
 [   4       2       0       1       5  ]
 [   inf     inf     1       0       3  ]
 [   3       4       5       3       0  ]]
```

If you just want to have a specific string output for a specific array, the function [numpy.array2string](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.array2string.html#numpy.array2string) is also available.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `set_printoptions` in NumPy.