# What does {:4} mean in this matrix printing solution in python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, printing, slice

In the solution to the question proposed here [printing a two dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870612/printing-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python) I'm not able to figure out what the {:4} part of the solution means exactly. I've tried this print statement and it seems to work very well, but for cases where I have very large matrices, I want to make sure I'm not adding or slicing valuable information.

Comment: Oh, fantastic! That makes a lot of sense. Thank you.

Comment: @ZdaR:  "*printed output to be of 4 characters at max*".  I think you meant at **minimum**.  If more than 4 characters are presented then they will be in the final string, if less then they will be padded.  The number is a minimum field width, just like in `printf "%4s"`. Try `"{:4}".format("123456")`.  As the doc says:  "*width is a decimal integer defining the minimum field width.*"  https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to do with padding and alignment in output. It is similar to padding in the `printf` function found in `c` or `awk`, etc. It gives each printed element a width of `n` where `n` is `{:n}`.

```
''.join('{:3}'.format(x) for x in range(100))
```

Will output:

```
'  0  1  2  3  4  5 ... 95 96 97 98 99'
```

Notice the single space to the left of `99` versus the two spaces to the left of `0`. In other words, each number has a width of 3 characters.

You can also accomplish a similar effect using a more traditional syntax.

```
''.join('%3s' % x for x in range(100))
```