# need ideas fix with space between numbers in python

Tags: python

This is the code:

```
def main():

    for i in range(1, 11):
        for j in range(1, 11):
            print(i*j, " ", end="")
        print()

main()
```

[image]

It should look like that with perfect lines and spaces between them. So how do i add spaces between them so that  i can see it in the print screen

Comment: You're never going to get something like that image out of `print`. You'd need something GUI-based for that.

Comment: Do you mean `fixed-width spaces`?

Comment: Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data) or [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870612/printing-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Comment: Try `print(" {:3d} ".format(i*j), " ", end="")`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ljust()`

This method returns the string left justified in a string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar (default is a space). The original string is returned if width is less than len(s).

Source : [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_ljust.htm)

```
for i in range(1, 11):
        for j in range(1, 11):
            print(str(i*j).ljust(2), " ", end="")
        print()
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work :)

```
def main():

    for i in range(1, 11):
        for j in range(1, 11):
            print('{:<3d}'.format(i*j), end="")
        print()

main()
```