# Matrix of sequence in Python

Tags: python, matrix, sequence

I have this code:

```
import random
def create_matrix(row, col):
    matrix = [["".join([random.choice("ATCG") for j in range(random.randint(1, 10))])
                  for _ in range(col)]
                  for _ in range(row)]
    return matrix
print(create_matrix(5, 4))
```

And I get this output:

```
[['CGCT', 'CATGC', 'GCAACTATA', 'AA'], ['TTTGGGAGTA', 'GGGCTGAA', 'GTT', 'GCTCGC'], ['ATTGT', 'CCG', 'ACC', 'GTG']
```

How can I get the same output but arranged in a matrix 3x4? Something like this but with the previous output.

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
17  18  19  20
```

Comment: [duplicated] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870612/printing-a-two-dimensional-array-in-python

Comment: Here there are some useful trick: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/print-matrix-python/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not concerned about spacing things nicely, a simple for loop to print each row at a time would work. ([Try Online](https://www.online-python.com/1hDMJokEtC))

```
import random
def create_matrix(row, col):
    matrix = [["".join([random.choice("ATCG") for j in range(random.randint(1, 10))])
                  for _ in range(col)]
                  for _ in range(row)]
    return matrix

matrix = create_matrix(5, 4)

for r in matrix:
    print(r)
```

With output:

```
['TTTG', 'TCT', 'ACTCGAGCTA', 'AA']
['TTAC', 'GT', 'T', 'CGGAC']
['GGCATGT', 'CCCTCCGTCC', 'GTCGAA', 'GTCATGTAG']
['TC', 'TTACGGTCT', 'TGGCAAAA', 'AGCCGGGGA']
['A', 'C', 'CT', 'AA']
```

Comment: Great! It was easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you use numpy, the output will be better formatted. But basically what you have is correct, it's just a matter of the code is outputted.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.array(create_matrix(5, 4)))
```

Will produce the following output:

```
[['CT' 'CA' 'CCAGTG']
 ['ACAGAA' 'AAT' 'C']
 ['ATCCAGAA' 'ATCGACCGTG' 'T']
 ['GACA' 'AACCGTAG' 'GCCACAGAC']
 ['TCAATT' 'TTTCAG' 'TACGCCTGA']]
```