# Using a list to get data(list in a list) (Python 3.7)

Tags: list, python-3.7

Is there a way to get list data within a list? a person name containing data(e.g. Grades) while the person is in a list.

list_name['Dan']['Physics']

returns 98

Comment: Then, it is dictionary, not a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look there are much ways to do that.

1- By for loop:

```py
# using for loop
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  
# printing the list using loop
for x in range(len(a)):
    print a[x],
```

-> output `1 2 3 4 5`

If you want to print 2D array ,I recommend you this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871279/16492410)