# How can i delete missing values in my csv_file

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

How can i delete missing values in my csv_file,either in a,b,c...:
This is my coding:

```
import numpy as np
FNAME ="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/table.csv"

my_data = np.genfromtxt (FNAME, delimiter = ',')
a= my_data [:,0]
b= my_data [:,1]
c= my_data [:,2]
d=my_data[:,3]
e= my_data[:,4]
f= my_data[:,5]
g= my_data[:,6]
```

An extract of my csv_file:

```
0,1,135,3,82,4,1
0,1,98,5,82,3,1
21175,1,98,5,82,3,1
9147,2,80,5,82,2,2
1829,2,80,5,82,2,2
3659,2,80,5,82,2,2
10976,2,80,5,82,2,2
0,2,40,2,24,1,2
0,2,40,2,24,1,2
29710,2,40,2,24,1,2
0,1,90,3,31,2,2
0,1,90,3,31,2,2
11434,1,90,3,31,2,2
0,2,85,4,72,3,2
6039,2,85,4,72,3,2
34758,1,100,,52,,
0,1,100,,52,,
```

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't clear from your question if you want to delete just values from the columns (which sounds wrong to me) or from all the columns. Either way it is better to use the power of `genfromtxt`. I recommend you read [this marvellous guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) or [just the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html).

In there you will find an argument `missing values` with this you could specify how you want to handle such occurrences when it is imported. There are many different ways to do this but one example could be using the fact that `genfromtxt` replaces missing floats with `nan`. Checking for the occurrence of `nan` in a row and disregarding if true:

```
import numpy as np
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """
0,4,1
34758,1,100
52,,
"""

my_data = np.genfromtxt(StringIO(data), delimiter=",")

index_to_use=[]
for i, row in enumerate(my_data):
    if True not in np.isnan(row):
        index_to_use.append(i)

print my_data[index_to_use]

>>>
[[  0.00000000e+00   4.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+00]
[  3.47580000e+04   1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+02]]
```

For readability I have reduced your data sample.

Comment: Instead of your `index_to_use` loop, you could use `np.isnan` in vectorized fashion: `my_data[~np.isnan(my_data).any(axis=1)]`.

Comment: In fact, I will wish to delete all the rows that contain missing values ​​in either a, b, c, d, e, f, g.

Comment: The suggestion I have given will remove the rows from all the columns (see the output line has 2 while the input csv data 3 rows). @DSM A very good point, I have not included it as I think it is less readable (there is quite a few obscured features such as `logical_not` hidden away). This would however be a preferred final solution, and most likely faster.

Comment: ok thanx but how can i make this result of my_data[index_to_use] in a csv_file?

Comment: If you mean save the resulting array in a csv file see [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has a built-in method for this:

```
from pandas import DataFrame, read_csv

FNAME ="C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/table.csv"
df = read_csv(FNAME, header=None, index_col=None)
print df.dropna()
```

Comment: `read_csv` is the preferred way to read a CSV file in to a `DataFrame`.