# To_CSV unique values of a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

When I use the following:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Z/OneDrive/Python/Exploratory Data/Aramark/ARMK.csv')
x = data.iloc[:,2]
y = pd.unique(x)
y.to_csv('yah.csv')
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Comment: `to_csv` is a [pandas.DataFrame method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), not a numpy array method. Turn your data into a pandas DataFrame or use the appropriate numpy method. Maybe [this'll be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)

Comment: By using pd.read_csv, isn't this a panas.DataFrame?

Comment: Shucks, you beat me to it, @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen! :P

Comment: `pd.unique()` returns a `numpy.ndarray`, as the error very obviously states.  `print(type(y))`

Comment: @ZJAY apparently not (I trust the interpreter). You can always call `type(your_variable)` at various points in your script to see the datatypes

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Ok, i'll just shut up now :D

Comment: What is the pandas equivalent for pd.unqiue()?  I'm basically trying to the dump the unique values of a column into an excel file.  What is the solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

IIUC, starting from a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'b':['a','a','b','c','c','b']})
```

you can get the unique values of a column with:

```
g = df['b'].unique()
```

that returns an array:

```
array(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=object)
```

to save it into a .csv file I would transform it into a `Series` s:

```
In [22]: s = pd.Series(g)

In [23]: s
Out[23]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object
```

So you can easily save it:

```
In [24]: s.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 6):

The pandas equivalent of `np.unique` is the [`drop_duplicates` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html).

```
In [42]: x = pd.Series([1,2,1,3,2])

In [43]: y = x.drop_duplicates()

In [46]: y
Out[46]: 
0    1
1    2
3    3
dtype: int64
```

---

Notice that `drop_duplicates` returns a Series, so you can call its `to_csv` method:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Z/OneDrive/Python/Exploratory Data/Aramark/ARMK.csv')
x = data.iloc[:,2]
y = x.drop_duplicates()
y.to_csv('yah.csv')
```