# How to save numpy ndarray as .csv file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I created a `numpy` array as follows:

```
import numpy as np

names  = np.array(['NAME_1', 'NAME_2', 'NAME_3'])
floats = np.array([ 0.1234 ,  0.5678 ,  0.9123 ])

ab = np.zeros(names.size, dtype=[('var1', 'U6'), ('var2', float)])
ab['var1'] = names
ab['var2'] = floats
```

The values in `ab` are shown below:

```
array([(u'NAME_1',  0.1234), (u'NAME_2',  0.5678), (u'NAME_3',  0.9123)],
      dtype=[('var1', '<U6'), ('var2', '<f8')])
```

When I try to save `ab` as a .csv file using `savetxt()` command,

```
np.savetxt('D:\test.csv',ab,delimiter=',')
```

I get below error

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-66-a71fd201aefe> in <module>()
> ----> 1 np.savetxt('D:\Azim\JF-Mapping-workflow-CRM\Backup\delete.csv',ab,delimiter=',')
>
> c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
>    1256                     raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
>    1257                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
> -> 1258                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))
>    1259         if len(footer) > 0:
>    1260             footer = footer.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)
>
> TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('[('var1', '<U6'), ('var2', '<f8')]') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e')
> ```

Comment: A general case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Comment: @Anton, thanks for sharing additional information.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your array include strings, but np default formatting is for floats.

Try manually setting the format:

```
np.savetxt(r'g:\test.csv',ab,delimiter=',', fmt=('%s, %f'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tested your code, its not working either. Edit: It's working perfectly fine.