# After doing ML how to save predicted output to CSV files using PANDAS lib or CSV lib

Tags: python, pandas, csv, machine-learning, scikit-learn

After doing Machine Learning in Python 3.5.x How to save predicted output to CSV files using PANDAS library or CSV library??

Answer (score 2):

If you have a pandas DataFrame `df`, it can be saved to a CSV file using [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) frunction.

```
df.to_csv("some_file.csv")
```

Comment: Im having a variable which i got after doing ML "y-pred". I would like to save that

Comment: What is the format y-pred? If it is in a pandas DataFrame, `df` and you just want to save a column called 'y-pred' you would call `df['y-pred'].to_csv(path)`, where path would be `'/some_folder/some_file_name.csv'`

Comment: It is in type  <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: You can save numpy arrays using: `numpy.savetxt("some_name.csv", some_numpy_array, delimiter=",")` : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file