# Writing python list as CSV

Tags: python

Just having a bit of a struggle getting the right formatting with the csv output files.

I have the following list called found in python:

```
   [['dropbearid', 'distance'],
    ['DB_1487', 17.543651156695343],
    ['DB_1901', 24.735333924441772],
    ['DB_2800', 6.607094868078008]]
```

When I use

```
import csv
out = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
out.writerow(found)
```

I get a file that when I open in excel has the values but it has 'dropbearid','distance' in one cell and 'DB_1487','17.54...' in the next cell and so on all continued across the first row.

Is there a way to get the output setup so 'dropbearid' and 'distance' are placed across two columns and all the list below are put in rows below?

Thanks!

Comment: For inserting each row you need to call `out.writerow` seperately, or you may use `out.writerows()`

Comment: Pretty easy way to do that using numpy here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. You write the list of lists to one row, which is why you have two values in one cell, because you write every element of `found` (which is a list of two elements) in a cell. You need to iterate over the list of lists and write every list to a row. This should work:

```
import csv
out = csv.writer(open("myfile.csv","w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, newline='')
for row in found:
    out.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Add newline='' in writerobj else you will end up in having blank lines in your file.

Answer (score 1):

The function `writerow()` will write a single row. So you need to use `writerows()` and set `newline` parameter as `''` to avoid blank rows in file.

```
found = [['dropbearid', 'distance'],
    ['DB_1487', 17.543651156695343],
    ['DB_1901', 24.735333924441772],
    ['DB_2800', 6.607094868078008]]
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    writer.writerows(found)
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
found = [['dropbearid', 'distance'],['DB_1487', 17.543651156695343],['DB_1901', 24.735333924441772],['DB_2800', 6.607094868078008]]
dffound = pd.DataFrame(found)
header = dffound.iloc[0]
dffound = dffound[1:]
dffound.rename(columns = header)
dffound.tocsv("enter path here")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas DataFrames for writing lists to CSV's, it makes formatting lot easier

```
import pandas as pd
dffound = pd.DataFrame(found,columns=['dropbearid', 'distance'])
dffound.to_csv('Found.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use the **writerows** function instead of **writerow**, to write each item of the sub-list as a column.

```
with open('myfile.csv', 'w+') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas library for this.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(found, columns=['dropbearid', 'distance'])
df = df.drop(0) # drop the header row
df.to_csv('Found.csv', index=False)
```