# How should I store my numpy arrays in file?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am running a simulation that creates various arrays and matrices every update cycle that I wish to store. The data is all numerical and ranges from scalars to 3 x 4 matrices. I would ideally save the data to a single file and wish to subsequently analyse the data in pandas. I have tried the `csv.DictWriter.writerow()` method but this saves the arrays as strings which I cannot do analysis on.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [numpy.savez](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) to save multiple numpy arrays into one file.

For analysing you can just load it with `numpy.load`

Comment: can savez be used to "append" arrays to a file iteratively?

Comment: As far as I know no, not directly. However you could `numpy.load` the file, then add the new entries to the list and then `numpy.savez` it again.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the fastest and simplest way of storing and loading your matrix data would be to store them in numpy binary format with `np.save` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html)
and then loading it back with numpy `load` before importing into pandas dataframe.

Binary format will give your speed advantage over any text based formats.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider the yaml library.

```
import yaml
import numpy as np

ary = np.zeros((2, 2, 2))
```

Save to file:

```
with open('numpy_to.yml', 'w') as outfile:
    yaml.dump(ary, outfile, default_flow_style=False)
```

Reload data:

```
with open("numpy_to.yml", 'r') as inputfile:
    ary_back = yaml.load(inputfile)

print(ary_back)

# [[[0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]

#  [[0. 0.]
#   [0. 0.]]]
```

---

If you want to store to a single file, you could `dump` a di`enter code here`ct:

```
zeros = np.zeros((2, 2, 2))
ones = np.ones((2, 2, 2))

my_numpies = { 'zeros': zeros, 'ones': ones}
```