# write or convert .data file to csv

Tags: python, csv

I will like to convert .data file to .csv in python. Basically I want to export this .data file into my working directory as a csv file.

```
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/spambase.data"
raw_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
mydataset = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to this answer 
[Dump a NumPy array into a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)

Also i think you don't need to load the data in numpy array as it is already in csv format. You can just write the raw data in a `.csv` file.

```
with open('csv_file.csv', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(raw_data.read())
```

That should suffice.

So to sum up, If you want to use use numpy to write the csv then

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import numpy as np

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/spambase.data"
raw_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
mydataset = np.loadtxt(raw_data, delimiter=",")
np.savetxt("foo.csv", mydataset, delimiter=",")
```

And easier and faster is to just write the raw data

```
import urllib.request as urllib
import numpy as np

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spambase/spambase.data"
raw_data = urllib.urlopen(url)
with open('csv_file.csv', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(raw_data.read())
```

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. my raw data is in .data format and my code is running fine. I just want to export my .data file to csv even without pandas.

Comment: What problem are you facing? Can you share the error?

Comment: I have made some changes in the answer, hope it helps