# multiple numpy array to csv python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, csv, numpy-ndarray

How can I save a in csv? Thank you all.

```
print(a)
```

['B17' 'B8' 'B19']

['B20' 'B16' 'B17']

['B27' 'B2' 'B3']

['B2' 'B22' 'B7']

['B30' 'B12' 'B28']

['B10' 'B8' 'B15']

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: a is coming from a loop, so only the last array is saved, how can i save all the array?

Comment: Use `np.vstack` to join the arrays into one multi-row array, and save that.

Answer (score 1):

Quick search on Stackoverflow provides an answer:

[Dump a NumPy array into a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)

Code pasted here, in case the link ever dies:

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```

The page also has useful alternate ways to convert it using pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Pandas` for this.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Actually, nvm, `numpy.savetxt` is the way better.