# Writing a CSV table from column variables?

Tags: python, csv

I am a total beginner in Python, so sorry if it is trivial but I can't solve the problem.

I have 3 lists containing floats.

```
mouse_x = [-0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01, -0.01]
mouse_y = [-0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888, -0.14888888888888888]
mouse_time = [1.5307196849607863, 1.581636800954584, 1.6135933389887214, 1.6362467749859206, 1.6675526530016214, 1.6996790579869412, 1.7314749069628306, 1.7635557259782217, 1.7962380870012566, 1.826124977960717]
```

What I want to do is to combine these three variables so that they are the 3 columns of my CSV file. It should look the following way:

```
mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_time
-0.01, -0.14888888888888888, 1.5307196849607863
-0.01, -0.14888888888888888, 1.581636800954584
-0.01, -0.14888888888888888, 1.6135933389887214
...
...
```

This is what I have tried:

```py
with open('my_file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['mouse_x', 'mouse_y', 'mouse_time'])
    counter = 0
    for x in mouse_x_list:
        thewriter.writerows(mouse_x_list[counter], mouse_y_list[counter], mouse_time_list[counter])
        counter +=1
```

This produces the following error:

> TypeError: writerows() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: CSV wirter only allows one argument. Throw it into a loop and write the item from each list in that index.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `writerows` to `writerow` and wrap the three arguments into a list `[...]`:

```
thewriter.writerow ( [mouse_x_list[counter], mouse_y_list[counter], mouse_time_list[counter]])
```

[`csv.writerows`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) expects a *row* object, but `writerow` also accepts simple lists -- as you used earlier to write out the header.

Unrelated, but you can omit the `counter` by using `zip` to weave those three lists into one:

```
for a,b,c in zip(mouse_x_list,mouse_y_list,mouse_time_list):
    thewriter.writerow ( [a,b,c])
```

Comment: Even simpler would be to omit the loop and just do `thewriter.writerows(zip(mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_time))`

Comment: For what it's worth, I've got an example of how to implement tfw's suggestion to use `zip` in my own answer. Looks like tfw and I thought pretty much alike here.

Answer (score 1):

Would you accept to use `numpy`? I find it to be very straightforward for this kind of applications:

You generate a multidimensional array for which each column is one of your lists:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_time])
```

In this way you can access `mouse_x` with `arr[:, 0]`, `mouse_y` with `arr[:, 1]` and `mouse_time` with `arr[:, 2]`.

Once you have this data structure, `numpy` ships a builtin function to save arrays:

```
np.savetxt('mouse.csv', arr.T, delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can write your CSV file without using NumPy or Pandas:

```py
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['mouse_x', 'mouse_y', 'mouse_time'])
    len_rows = len(mouse_x)
    for counter in range(len_rows):
        thewriter.writerow([mouse_x[counter], mouse_y[counter], mouse_time[counter]])
```

Notice that you don't need to increment a `counter` variable yourself here; the `for` statement in conjunction with `range()` already sets `counter` to 0, 1, and so on. Notice that in the `for` loop, I'm using `writerow` *not* `writerows`.

An arguably more "Pythonic" way to write the CSV file with a `for` loop would be to do this:

```py
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['mouse_x', 'mouse_y', 'mouse_time'])
    for mx, my, mtime in zip(mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_time):
        thewriter.writerow([mx, my, mtime])
```

Now, `writerows()` takes an *iterable* of rows, for example, a list or tuple of rows. An iterable, loosely speaking, is what you'd put after the "`in`" in a `for` statement. If you had, say, a list of tuples, where tuple `i` in the list was `(mouse_x[i], mouse_y[i], mouse_time[i])`, then you could pass that list of tuples to `writerows()` and be done with it. Alternatively, one could use `zip(mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_time)` from the above `for` loop *itself* as an argument of `writerows()`:

```py
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
    thewriter.writerow(['mouse_x', 'mouse_y', 'mouse_time'])
    thewriter.writerows(zip(mouse_x, mouse_y, mouse_time))
```

Arguably, that's even more Pythonic, for whatever that's worth.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame([mouse_x,mouse_y,mouse_time])
df.T.to_csv('my_file.csv', index=False, header=['mouse_x','mouse_y','mouse_time'])
```

Comment: I've deleted the last parenthesis and it worked as well! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas to make a dataframe first and than save it as an csv-file:

```
     import pandas as pd

     df = pd.DataFrame()
     df.insert(0, 'mouse_x', mouse_x)
     df.insert(1, 'mouse_y', mouse_y)
     df.insert(2, 'mouse_time', mouse_time)
     df
```

output:

```
        mouse_x mouse_y mouse_time
      0 -0.01   -0.148889   1.530720
      1 -0.01   -0.148889   1.581637
      2 -0.01   -0.148889   1.613593
      3 -0.01   -0.148889   1.636247
      4 -0.01   -0.148889   1.667553
      5 -0.01   -0.148889   1.699679
      6 -0.01   -0.148889   1.731475
      7 -0.01   -0.148889   1.763556
      8 -0.01   -0.148889   1.796238
      9 -0.01   -0.148889   1.826125
```

save to csv:

```
     df.to_csv('name_file.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is one of the best libraries regarding data stored in arrays. It also includes implementations to save arrays to file directly. Check out how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081043/12852291) .