# Parse strings of numbers separated by whitespace to list of lists python

Tags: python, csv

I have a txt file as following:

```
12 13 14 15
78 79 80 90
45 63 29 78
```

I want to convert it into a list of lists so as to have:

```
[[12,13,14,15],[78,79,80,90],[45,63,29,78]]
```

Comment: How about the use of `numpy`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to convert to a CSV, or a python list of lists?

Comment: In reality I thought I needed to convert it into a csv file to do so but I actually need to convert it into a list of lists @HalJarrett

Comment: @stud_eco You should edit your question to reflect that, then.

Comment: With that out of the way, can you clarify what the issue is? There are plenty of resources on the subject already.

Comment: I think this is now a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585078/how-do-i-read-and-write-csv-files-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1.

Answer (score 2):

```
import csv

# read the data (space delimited)
with open('data.txt',newline='') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f,delimiter=' '))

# data is list of lists, but strings
print(data)

# convert to integers if needed
ints = [[int(n) for n in row] for row in data]
print(ints)

# write back out as true CSV
with open('data.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    csv.writer(f).writerows(data) # data or ints will write correctly.
```

Output:

```
[['12', '13', '14', '15'], ['78', '79', '80', '90'], ['45', '63', '29', '78']]
[[12, 13, 14, 15], [78, 79, 80, 90], [45, 63, 29, 78]]
```

data.csv:

```
12,13,14,15
78,79,80,90
45,63,29,78
```

Comment: I get IOPub data rate exceeded.
The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output
to the client in order to avoid crashing it.
To change this limit, set the config variable
`--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.

Current values:
NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit=1000000.0 (bytes/sec)
NotebookApp.rate_limit_window=3.0 (secs)

Comment: @stud_eco That's fine, it just means you're printing to stdout too much.