# How to extract specific columns without index no. and with all the rows in python dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#df

index  a   b   c
1      2   3   4
2      3   4   5
```

## Please help me how to extract columns "a" and "c" with all the rows but without the index column.

df[["a","c"]] # But index no. is also coming, so how to remove the index no.?

Comment: `df[["a","c"]].values`

Comment: `df.reset_index(drop=True)[["a", "c"]]`

Comment: @Andrew, I tried with your code but getting array output.

Comment: @Riccardo, I tried with your code but only dropping the column name "Index", but other records of the column is still available.

Answer (score 12):

DataFrames and Series will always have an index, you can use:

```
df[["a","c"]].values
```

output:

```
array([[2, 4],
       [3, 5]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I wnat to export the file in csv, my code is:  df[["b","c"]].to_csv("C:\\Desktop\\File.csv") ; but still unable remove the Index column.

Comment: this is correct. But it is not completely solved my issue. Let me know if you have any solution for this.

Comment: @Goutam to save to a CSV you can use:`numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")` where `a = df[["a","c"]].values`

Comment: you can have a look over https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to achieve what the OP was specifically asking for is to add the index parameter as follows. e.g.

```
df[["b","c"]].to_csv("C:\\Desktop\\File.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for your case:

```
# import pandas package as pd
import pandas as pd
  
# Define a dictionary containing students data
data = {'a': [2, 3],
        'b': [3, 4],
        'c': [4, 5]}
  
# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b','c'])
  
print("Given Dataframe :\n", df)
  
print("\nIterating over rows using iloc function :\n")
  
# iterate through each row and select
# 0th and 2nd index column respectively.
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(df.iloc[i, 0], df.iloc[i, 2])
```

Output:

```
Given Dataframe :
    a  b  c
0  2  3  4
1  3  4  5

Iterating over rows using iloc function :

2 4
3 5
```

Tested here:

https://onecompiler.com/python/3zht3ravp

Solution source -
**Method 3: Using iloc[] function of the DataFrame.** :

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Also this reference for the slice operator explanation:
`[row_start:row_end , column_start, column_end]

where,

row_start refers start row with 0 position as index
row_end refers last row with n th  position as index
column_start refers start column with 0 position as index
column_end refers last column with n th position as index`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-first-column-of-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: Other methods here as well https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mT-2AxZLtvw