# how to write data row wise in csv file by following code?

Tags: python, csv

I am getting an error while running the following code, how do I fix it?

Error:

csv.Error: iterable expected, not numpy.int64

```
y_test = np.array(test_labels)
print('y_test_labels:', y_test.shape) # (230,123)

with open('/content/drive/My Drive/GEINet_and_PEINet/VGG_CSV/test.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
    employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    #employee_writer.writerow(y_test)
    x,y = y_test.shape
     print('x: ',x)
    for num in range(0, x):
        employee_writer.writerows(y_test[num,:])
```

Comment: u can directly dump numpy array to csv file, see if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `writerows` directly on the array:

```
employee_writer.writerows(y_test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead
`employee_writer.writerows(list(y_test[num,:]))`

Answer (score 0):

You should make `y_test[num,:]` iterable, modifying it to be a sequence of lists you can replace `y_test[num,:]` with `map(lambda x: [x], y_test[num,:])`.
Another way is instead of making a NumPy array`y_test`, making an iterable out of the `test_labels` data frame using `to_csv()` method from pandas`Series` from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
with open('/content/drive/My Drive/GEINet_and_PEINet/VGG_CSV/test.csv', mode='w') as employee_file:
    employee_writer.writerows(y_test)
```