# Python: writing elements from a list into CSV file without brackets or quotes

Tags: python, list, csv, quotes, brackets

I am struggeling with the elements of a list written to CSV file.

I wrote a Python script selecting some 25 human languages from a CSV file and put them into a list. The idea is to randomly create content that can result into a fake CV for machine learning:

```
# languages
all_langs = []
    
#populate languges from a central language csv
with open('sprachen.csv', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    file_reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in file_reader:
        if row[0] == "Sprache":
            continue
        else:
            all_langs.append(format(row[0]))
```

After that, I create a new empty list and fill it with the initial languages in a range from 0 to 3:

```
lang_skills = []
ran_number = random.randint(1,3)
for i in range(0,ran_number):
    lang_skills.append(str(all_langs[random.randint(0,len(all_langs)-1)]))
```

When I print the **lang_skills** it looks like this:

```
['Urdu', 'Ukrainian', 'Swedish']
```

In the last step, I want to write the **lang_skills** into a new CVS file.

```
with open('liste.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=';',quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerow(lang_skills)
```

However, the CSV looks like this:

```
Language
"Urdu";"Ukrainian";"Swedish"
...
```

How can write the output like this:

```
Language
"Urdu, Ukrainian, Swedish"; ...
...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dump a NumPy array into a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to write a *string* to the CSV, not a list; you want to write the string `"Urdu, Ukrainian, Swedish"` to the file, so you need to produce that string beforehand. Try joining the languages with `", ".join(lang_skills)`.

Comment: Good approach. I added:

`lang_skills = " ".join(lang_skills)`

Now the result looks like this:

`T;ü;r;k;i;s;c;h; ;F;r;a;n;z;ö;s;i;s;c;h; ;H;i;n;d;i`

Comment: Looks like you need to wrap the result in an iterable, e.g. `lang_skills = [" ".join(lang_skills)]`. It's treating each character as its own "cell."

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your list into a pandas dataframe, to create a CSV you need the columns name and your list of value:

```
import pandas as pd
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': my_list})
df.to_csv("path/csv_name.csv")
```