# How to write multiple matrix into excel in python

Tags: python, excel, matrix, scipy, mat

I have a .mat file that I opened it in python. It's a (6*6*365) matrix. I want to write this to a Excel file. How can I di it?
I open it by following code:

import scipy.io
mat= scipy.io.loadmat('2003.mat')

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the builtin csv library:
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html

or use NumPy instead using this method:
[Dump a NumPy array into a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)

I generally recommend NumPy, but I don't think there is a significant difference here.