# Module: tf.keras.datasets. Set where (directory) to download the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, dataset

I'm using tf.keras.datasets to download CIFAR 10 dataset and I wondering where the images are downloaded.

I've been searching if there is a function to set where to download the images, but I haven't found any. I have searched over the Internet and the only thing I have found is how to create my own dataset using Tensorflow.

My code is:

```
from tensorflow.keras import datasets

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = datasets.cifar10.load_data()

# Normalize pixel values to be between 0 and 1
train_images, test_images = train_images / 255.0, test_images / 255.0
```

How can I set where to download the images before using the function `load_data()`?

Comment: I don't think you can set the download folder, what would be the point of doing that?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Because I want to delete them when they are not used anymore and to check if they are download and if I use them very often, they will be downloaded every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/datasets/cifar10.py), the output `(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels)` are "Tuple of Numpy arrays". Therefore, when you call `load_data()` they are loaded into your memory from their origin ([https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Ekriz/cifar-10-python.tar.gz)). If you want to download them as well, you will have to do that separately on your own (some inspiration could be taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file)). Remember, the function name is `load_data()`, and not `download_data()`, where `load` refers to memory, and `download` refers to disk.

Comment: You are not answering the question that was asked.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Could you expand?

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to this conversation but on Windows check here,
`C:\Users\username\.keras\datasets`