# How to easily extract numpy arrays (Matrices) from python to excel?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, export

Fairly new to coding. I am working on a code and the outcome is below. How do I extract this output as an excel file or Mathematica format (which I reckon would be in C code)? I have come across USA Panda but it looked far too complex.

Here is an example of one of the matrices:

```
[[ 153181.46111548  -21602.51374705  -76590.73055774  -54988.21681068
    65298.50746269    -490.96622152  -65298.50746269     490.96622152]
 [ -21602.51374705  153181.46111548  -54988.21681068  -76590.73055774
      490.96622152  -65298.50746269    -490.96622152   65298.50746269]
 [ -76590.73055774  -54988.21681068  153181.46111548  -21602.51374705
   -65298.50746269     490.96622152   65298.50746269    -490.96622152]
 [ -54988.21681068  -76590.73055774  -21602.51374705  153181.46111548
     -490.96622152   65298.50746269     490.96622152  -65298.50746269]
 [  65298.50746269     490.96622152  -65298.50746269    -490.96622152
   283778.47604085  108994.50117832 -141889.23802042 -250883.73919874]
 [   -490.96622152  -65298.50746269     490.96622152   65298.50746269
   108994.50117832  283778.47604085 -250883.73919874 -141889.23802042]
 [ -65298.50746269    -490.96622152   65298.50746269     490.96622152
  -141889.23802042 -250883.73919874  283778.47604085  108994.50117832]
 [    490.96622152   65298.50746269    -490.96622152  -65298.50746269
  -250883.73919874 -141889.23802042  108994.50117832  283778.47604085]]
```

Comment: You can [save it as a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081043/11659881). Excel can import `csv`s. `pandas` also provides a simple command for writing directly to excel files. While the library itself is complex, you only need to use a small subset of methods and classes from it, and they are worthwhile to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using NumPy as per your question title you could use the following [Dump a NumPy array into a csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081008/dump-a-numpy-array-into-a-csv-file) you can use numpy [numpy.savetxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

This would result in the following code:

```
import numpy

numpy.savetxt('your\location\yourfile.csv', numpy_array,  delimiter=',')
```