# How to export elements generated on the console as a .csv table?

Tags: python

How do I tabulate the luminosity distances for all the galaxies in the form of .csv? The code for this bit is at the very last one. Thank you!

```
seed =  170777306


from astropy.io import ascii 
from astropy.cosmology import FlatLambdaCDM 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

#Read in data file
table_file = "galaxy_data.csv"
data = ascii.read(table_file)

#Set up cosmology for later calculating luminosity distances
cosmo = FlatLambdaCDM(H0=70, Om0=0.3, Tcmb0=2.725)

#Print information on table length (i.e., number of galaxies) and columns
print(data.info) 

# Print some information for random galaxy index
rng = np.random.default_rng(seed)
a = rng.integers(low=0,high=10000)
b = rng.integers(low=0,high=10000)
print('The object ID of galaxy indexed ',a,'is : ',data['objID'][a])
print('The object ID of galaxy indexed ',b,'is : ',data['objID'][b])
print('RA of galaxy indexed',a,'is: ',data['RA'][a]) 
print('RA of galaxy indexed',b,'is: ',data['RA'][b]) 

#Calculate and print luminosity distance for Galaxy A
lumDist = cosmo.luminosity_distance(data['redshift'][a]) #returns in Mpc
print('The redshift of galaxy indexed ',a,'is :',data['redshift'][a])
print('At this redshift, for our cosmology, the luminosity distance (in Mpc) is: ',lumDist.value)

#Calculate and print luminosity distance for Galaxy B
lumDist = cosmo.luminosity_distance(data['redshift'][b]) #returns in Mpc
print('The redshift of galaxy indexed ',b,'is :',data['redshift'][b])
print('At this redshift, for our cosmology, the luminosity distance (in Mpc) is: ',lumDist.value)

#Print RA and DEC of the first 10 galaxies (rows)
print("RA and DEC of first 10 galaxies")
print(data['RA','DEC'][0:10]) #print first 10 rows of columns RA and DEC (this prints rows 0->9)

#Print RA and DEC of all galaxies with redshift z<0.01 and h-band magnitude <17
selected_gals = np.where((data['redshift']<0.01) & (data['g']<17))
print("RA and DEC of galaxies with z<0.01 and g<17")
print(data['RA','DEC'][selected_gals])

#Calculate and print luminosity distance for all galaxies
lumDist = cosmo.luminosity_distance(data['redshift']) #returns in Mpc
print('The redshifts of all the galaxies:' ,data['redshift'])
print('At these redshifts, for our cosmology, the luminosity distances (in Mpc): ',lumDist.value)
```

I need to export it in order to tabulate it as there are 10000 rows so it's impossible to do it manually.

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Would this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081043/683329

Comment: What columns do you want in your csv? And for all galaxies [0:10000]?

Comment: @SargeATM yes for all galaxies, just 1 column with the elements produced for luminosity distances

Comment: @toyotaSupra apologies, it's my first time posting here. All done

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899103/writing-a-list-to-a-file-with-python-with-newlines  replace `lines` in example with `lumDist.value`