# write in file with python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I am searching for the easiest way to save an array in a file. For this I would want to use  numpy.savetxt but the problem is that my array is composed of n columns (the number depends on what i ant to do) and it contains complex elements (x+yj). I know how to save it if there is one column and real elements but I don't know how to do.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Sorry I'm not allowed to comment but have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file.   yay that actually worked as a comment

Comment: I red it but there is not a very short answer. In fact I want to write something like 'numpy.savetext('myfile',myarray,fmt=???)'.

Comment: Have you tried the examples I gave? I ran them in the interpreter so I know they work. Does the output have to be human readable?

Answer (score 2):

You could [pickle](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html) them:

```
>>> A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4+2j]])
>>> pickle.dump(A, open("out.pkl", "wb"))
>>> pickle.load(open("out.pkl", "rb"))
array([[ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j],
       [ 3.+0.j,  4.+2.j]])
```

However, it would be better to use [`numpy.save`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`numpy.load`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load), they're designed for this and will use a lot less space.

```
>>> np.save("out.npy", A)
>>> np.load("out.npy")
array([[ 1.+0.j,  2.+0.j],
       [ 3.+0.j,  4.+2.j]])
```

Comment: I already tried this and the answer is 'Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))'

Comment: `numpy.savetxt` gives that output, not `numpy.save`. The `savetxt` function produces human readable output, and it doesn't work for this.

Comment: +1 on numpy.save , if you're not going to use it outside of Python.