# 2d numpy array to text file

Tags: arrays, numpy, text-files

I have a 3D-array storing temperature data. And me want to put it to text file in one single line. Need to re-write this code in pythonic way.

```
    for jn in range(X1, X2):
        for jm in range(Y1,Y2):
            fl.write(str((t[jn,jm] - 273.1).astype(int))+" ")
    fl.write("\n")
```

Comment: What does your output look like when you do this?

Comment: File has one line like as 23 24 25 ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your array to save is `t`:

```
t.tofile('yourfile.txt',sep=" ",format="%s")
```

Also see this question:

[How to write a multidimensional array to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file/18145279#18145279)

Answer (score 2):

```
values = ("{0:.0f}".format(t[i,j]-273.1) 
                for i in xrange(X1, X2) 
                for j in xrange(Y1,Y2))
line = " ".join(values)
fl.write(line + "\n")
```