# plotting function from python

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, gnuplot

This is a direct continuation of my recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22475557/writing-an-array-to-disk-in-python/22475730?noredirect=1#22475730), which is solved.
I am re-posting the code here as well for integrity:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
xdata = np.array([0.1639534, 0.2411005, 0.3130353, 0.3788510,  0.4381247, 0.5373147, 0.6135673, 0.6716365, 0.7506711,  0.8000908, 0.9000000])
ydata =np.array ([7.1257999E-04,9.6610998E-04,1.1894000E-03,1.3777000E-03,1.5285000E-03,1.7297000E-03,1.8226000E-03,1.8422999E-03,1.7741000E-03,1.6574000E-03,1.1877000E-03])

def func (x,a,b,c):
    return a+b*x+c*x**3
popt, pcov =curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata,p0=(1,1,1))

with open('5fit','w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(' '.join(str(val) for val in popt))
```

Now, for plotting those data, I use `gnuplot`, as:

```
gnuplot> a=-5.20906980e-05
gnuplot> b=4.41458412e-03
gnuplot> c=-3.65246935e-03
gnuplot> p a+b*x+c*x**3 w l
```

I generally follow [this](https://klassenresearch.orbs.com/Plotting+with+Python) for plotting a function or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12311767/how-to-plot-files-with-numpy) for data file.
But now, I need to plot that function(`a+b*x+c*x**3`) using those data given by `popt`. I also need to save them in pdf/png format.

Kindly help me doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the code below to plot both your data and your fitted function. I have imported `matplotlib.pyplot` at the top (as `plt`) and used two simple plots to your data.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xdata = np.array([0.1639534, 0.2411005, 0.3130353, 0.3788510,  0.4381247, 0.5373147, 0.6135673, 0.6716365, 0.7506711,  0.8000908, 0.9000000])
ydata =np.array ([7.1257999E-04,9.6610998E-04,1.1894000E-03,1.3777000E-03,1.5285000E-03,1.7297000E-03,1.8226000E-03,1.8422999E-03,1.7741000E-03,1.6574000E-03,1.1877000E-03])

def func (x,a,b,c):
    return a+b*x+c*x**3
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func,xdata,ydata,p0=(1,1,1))

# Plot your original data
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, linestyle='None', marker='x', label='Data')
# Plot your fit using the xdata as x-values and func() to generate the y-values.
plt.plot(xdata, func(xdata, *popt), label='Fit')

plt.legend()

plt.show()

plt.savefig('image.png') # Save the figure.
```

The use of `func(xdata, *popt)` could have been written alternatively as `func(xdata, popt[0], popt[1], popt[2])` however this is the more [pythonic way](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) to achieve the same end.

[`plt.savefig`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.savefig) can be used to save the current figure if you need to output it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you mentioned gnuplot: Here is how you can do the fitting and plotting with gnuplot:

Save the data to a file `data.txt`:

```
0.1639534 7.1257999E-04
0.2411005 9.6610998E-04
0.3130353 1.1894000E-03
0.3788510 1.3777000E-03
0.4381247 1.5285000E-03
0.5373147 1.7297000E-03
0.6135673 1.8226000E-03
0.6716365 1.8422999E-03
0.7506711 1.7741000E-03
0.8000908 1.6574000E-03
0.9000000 1.1877000E-03
```

and use the script:

```
set terminal pdfcairo
set output 'output.pdf'

f(x) = a+b*x+c*x**3
fit f(x) 'data.txt' via a,b,c
plot 'data.txt' with points, f(x) with lines
set output
```

The result with version 4.6.3 is:

[image]