# Write data to file

Tags: python, scala, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I am trying to write a matrix (`<type 'numpy.ndarray'>`) in a file, with this format:

> index_of_row # v0, v1, v2

which will be read by my partner's Scala code (if that matters).

After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file), I ended up with this code:

```
print dense_reduced
# this will give an error:
#TypeError: expected a single-segment buffer object
#f = open('dense.txt','w')
#f.write(dense_reduced[0])
#f.close()
numpy.savetxt('dense.txt', dense_reduced, delimiter=", ", fmt="%s")
```

which outputs:

```
[[-0.17033304  0.13854157  0.22427917]
..
 [-0.15361054  0.38628932  0.05236084]]
```

and the dense.txt is:

```
-0.170333043895, 0.138541569519, 0.224279174382
...
```

**However**, there are *several* reasons I need the dense.txt to look like this (index of row of the matrix # values separated by comma):

```
0 # -0.17033304,  0.13854157,  0.22427917
...
```

How to proceed?

Comment: what is dense_reduced?

Comment: Forgot to mention that @Goodies, updated.

Comment: `delimiter` and `fmt` parameters will correct most of the line.  I'm not sure about adding the line counter.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, I updated my question, I think now it's better, but still unable to complete my goal.

Comment: So `fmt` gets you all the way there!  `savetxt` just iterates over the rows of the input array, writing a string created with `fmt%tuple(row)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `savetext()` options :

```
u = dense_reduced
w = np.hstack((np.arange(u.shape[0]).reshape(-1,1),u))
np.savetxt('dense.txt', w, fmt=["%i #"]+ ["%.10s, "]*(u.shape[1]-1)+["%.10s"])
```

for :

```
0 # 0.57105063,  0.70274226,  0.87870916
1 # 0.28735507,  0.94860021,  0.63763897 
2 # 0.26302099,  0.26609319,  0.75001683 
3 # 0.93315750,  0.19700358,  0.13632004
```

You can also simplify with `w=pd.DataFrame(u).reset_index()` if you have pandas.

Comment: I do not want to restraint the decimal digits, so I just discard the 5 you have?

Comment: Wow, I stand corrected. I couldn't figure it out with np.savetxt. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

There are several options that you can provide in numpy.savetxt (such as comments, delimiter, etc) but I don't believe you can do it in this way. A multidimensional np array can be used as an iterable of smaller arrays, so we can easily run:

```
my_array = np.array(range(20)).reshape((4,5))
f = open("output.txt", "w")
for i, a in enumerate(my_array):
    f.write("{} # {}".format(i, ', '.join(list(map(str, a)))))
f.close()
```

Comment: This will put everything in *one line*. What about `f.write("{} # {}\n".format(i, ', '.join(list(map(str, a)))))`? :)