# TypeError when using np.savetxt to save a collection of three lists to .csv

Tags: python, numpy

I am using Python to parse an ascii file and create a .csv with three columns of 'day', 'time' and 'z'

I am able to populate 'day' 'time' and 'z' with values parsed from input.txt using this:

```
import numpy as np

f = open ('input.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
day=[];time=[];z=[]
for line in lines:
    lstrip = line.strip()
    if not lstrip.startswith('#'):
        words=lstrip.split('  ')
        day.append(words[0])
        time.append(words[1])
        z.append(words[2])
```

however when I try the following:

```
zipped = zip(day, time, z)
np.savetxt('output.csv', zipped, delimiter=",", header="day, time, z", comments="")
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S15') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')
```

Is there a way I can set the datatypes of the lists to avoid this error?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving numpy array to csv produces TypeError Mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36552858/saving-numpy-array-to-csv-produces-typeerror-mismatch)

Comment: The error indicates that `zipped`, when converted to an array has strings, not numbers.  The default format for `savetxt` is scientific notation for numbers (float or integer).  Try `x=np.array(zipped)`, and report on the `.shape` and `.dtype`.  And read `savetxt` documentation about `fmt`.

Comment: While I like my answer in Eli's link, I don't think it applies here.  There the first problem was that the array was 3d.  Here the problem is that is contains strings.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will look into this. The '.shape' of the 'np.array(zipped)' is '(1800000L, 3L)' - which is maxed out as I understand it. The '.dtype' is '|S15'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can replicate your problem with:

```
x=['one','two','three']
y=['a','b','c']    
z=['1','2','3'] 
zz=list(zip(x,y,z))   # py3

zz
Out[58]: [('one', 'a', '1'), ('two', 'b', '2'), ('three', 'c', '3')]

za=np.array(zz)    # make list an array; note the dtype

za
Out[60]: 
array([['one', 'a', '1'],
       ['two', 'b', '2'],
       ['three', 'c', '3']], 
      dtype='<U5')

np.savetxt('test',zz)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
...
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('<U5') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

Same sort of error when trying to write strings as floats.  But if I change the format to a string one:

```
np.savetxt('test',za,fmt='%10s')

cat test
       one          a          1
       two          b          2
     three          c          3
```

If your inputs really are numbers then you could convert the string to numbers while building the lists.

Another option is to write the list to the `csv` directly (with file write) or with the Python `csv` module.