# TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with dimension 1000*30*150. I am trying to save it as txt file. So far I have tried this

```
np.savetxt("test.txt", mydata, fmt='%.5f', delimiter=",")
#and 
with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for row in mydata:
        np.savetxt(f, row, delimiter=',', fmt='%.5f')
```

both method give me error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1254, in savetxt
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):


        np.savetxt("test.txt", train, fmt='%.5f', delimiter=",")
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1258, in savetxt
        % (str(X.dtype), format))
    TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('float64') and format specifier ('%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not mention what is the purpose of writing the 3-d array to a text file, would you be reading it back in the future, and what format are you looking for, but that is one possibility:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(mydata, default=lambda x: list(x), indent=4))
```

If you clarify the purpose, people will be able to suggest better suited solutions.

Comment: how can I save this in a text or json file?

Comment: `with open('test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(json.dumps(mydata, default=lambda x: list(x), indent=4))`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your array is 3 dimensional and can't be saved in a 2 dimensional format. Either reshape it, so that it is 2d:

```
mydata = mydata.reshape(mydata.shape[0],mydata.shape[1]*mydata.shape[2])
np.savetxt('text.txt',mydata,fmt='%.5f',delimiter=',')
```

or if you do not need to read it as a text file and want to just reload it later in python use:

```
np.save('text.npy',mydata)
```

Comment: .@djk47463 - I get similar error `Mismatch between array dtype ('float32') and format specifier ('%.18e,%.18e,%.18e')`. Can you please explain `reshape` for this (I am new to `numpy`). The data I have can be saved in `.npy`, but I need raw text files to check the weights it's storing.

Comment: @ChetanArvindPatil, when using [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), you are either reducing or increasing the dimensions.  In this example, OP has a 3d array, with a length of 1000.  Keeping the first dimision the same, we combine the 2nd and 3rd dimensions. So in a given row, in the csv 150 observations would be equivalent to one timestep from the second dimension

Answer (score 1):

Tell us about `mydata`.  In particular its `dtype` and `shape`.

To save with `%.5f` format it needs to be a 2d array of numbers.

`savetxt` does, roughly:

```
 for row in arr:
   print(format % tuple(row))
```

where `format` is constructed from your `fmt` parameter, and the number columns in the array.  It looks like your array has a large number of columns, so `format` is that `'%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%.5f,%...` string.

`tuple` is needed to turn that 1d array `row` into a tuple that works with `format%()`.

If the array is higher dimensions, or an array of objects, it would have problems.

---

edit - so you say the array is 1000*30*150.  So it tries to iterate on the 1000 rows, 30 looks like the size of that `format`.  But it can't apply that to a `(30,150)` array.

With the `open` and `row` iteration, do you get the same error?  In Py3 you might need to open with `'wb'.  Iterating yourself on the first dimension means each`savetxt`call works with a 30x150 array.  It will iterate on the 30, and try to format rows of 150.  The would create a larger`format`, but I think that would run.

In any case, `savetxt` is designed for 2d numeric arrays. 3d requires some sort of fudge.  Keep in mind also that `csv` readers aren't designed for 3d arrays either.  They expect rows with consistent columns separated by a simple delimiter.

---

```
In [260]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(4,3,2)
```

It can work with 3d - if allowed to format each subrow with `%s`:

```
In [261]: np.savetxt('test',arr, fmt='%s')
In [262]: cat test
[0 1] [2 3] [4 5]
[6 7] [8 9] [10 11]
[12 13] [14 15] [16 17]
[18 19] [20 21] [22 23]
```

3d numeric format - error

```
In [263]: np.savetxt('test',arr, fmt='%d')
....
TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('int32') and format specifier ('%d %d %d')
```

Reshape 3d to 2d - save works:

```
In [264]: np.savetxt('test',arr.reshape(-1,2), fmt='%d')
In [265]: cat test
0 1
2 3
4 5
6 7
8 9
...
22 23
```

With an extra iteration; could add a blank line between blocks

```
In [267]: with open('test','wb') as f:
     ...:     for row in arr:
     ...:         np.savetxt(f, row, '%d',delimiter=', ')
     ...:         
In [268]: cat test
0, 1
2, 3
4, 5
6, 7
...
22, 23
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to **np.savetxt()** could be using the csv module:

```
with open("filename.","w+") as my_csv:            # writing the file as my_csv
    csvWriter = csv.writer(my_csv,delimiter=',')  # using the csv module to write the file
    csvWriter.writerows(array_2d)                 # write every row in the matrix
```

I have encountered a similar TypeError problem with numpy, but the CSV method seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to write the data out in formatted rows and columns along the axis at `mydata[i,:,:]` with the intention of producing something in a more readable table format, see this answer:  [How to write a multidimensional array to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file) by @JoeKington. My code adds a loop through the rows and columns of each slice because I couldn't find any other resolution to a TypeError I was getting when implementing the original code:

```
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        # Add header giving shape of array
        # Any line starting with "#" will be ignored by numpy.loadtxt
        outfile.write('# Array shape: {0}\n'.format(x_train.shape))

        # Iterating through a ndimensional array produces slices along
        # the last axis. This is equivalent to data[i,:,:] in this case
        sliceCount = 0
        for data_slice in x_train:
            # Keep track of the slice numbers
            outfile.write('# New slice %d\n'%sliceCount)

            # Work through each row and column of the 2d numpy array inside the 
            # slice, writing each column number to file in format of your choosing
            for row in data_slice:
                for col in row:
                    itemStr = "%8.6f,"%col
                    outfile.write(itemStr)
                outfile.write("\n")

            sliceCount += 1
```