# How to write a multi dimensional numpy array to a csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a multi dimensional numpy arrray. I want to dump that array to a csv file. Please suggest methods of how it can be done. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a multidimensional array to a text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file)

Comment: A proper csv is table like, so can easily show a 2d array.  3d or higher doesn't fit the format

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) and define `delimiter=','`.