# Numpy CSV fromfile()

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

I'm probably trying to reinvent the wheel here, but numpy has a `fromfile()` function that can read - I imagine - CSV files.

It appears to be incredibly fast - even compared to Pandas `read_csv()`, but I'm unclear on how it works.

Here's some test code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create the file here, two columns, one million rows of random numbers.
filename = 'my_file.csv'
df  = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.randint(100,10000,1000000), 'b':np.random.randint(100,10000,1000000)})
df.to_csv(filename, index = False)

# Now read the file into memory.
arr = np.fromfile(filename)

print len(arr)
```

I included the `len()` at the end there to make sure  it wasn't reading just a single line.  But curiously, the length for me (will vary based on your random number generation) was 1,352,244.  Huh?

[The docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) show an optional `sep` parameter.  But when that is used:

```
arr = np.fromfile(filename, sep = ',')
```

...we get a length of 0?!

Ideally I'd be able to load a 2D array of arrays from this CSV file, but I'd settle for a single array from this CSV.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numpy.fromfile` is not made to read `.csv` files, instead, it is made for reading data written with the [`numpy.ndarray.tofile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html#numpy.ndarray.tofile) method.

From the docs:

> A highly efficient way of reading binary data with a known data-type, as well as parsing simply formatted text files. *Data written using the tofile method* can be read using this function.

By using it without a `sep` parameter, numpy assumes you are reading a binary file, hence the different lengths. When you specify a separator, I guess the function just breaks.

To read a `.csv` file using numpy, I think you can use `numpy.genfromtext` or `numpy.loadtxt` (from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy)).

Comment: Thanks araraonline, but to the part that says "parsing simply formatted text files" - what are those simply formatted text files then?  You'd think they should be able to be created in any text editor and not require `numpy.tofile`

Comment: I've experimented here with `tofile` and it seems they are just an array of numbers split by `sep`. For example: `"1,2,3,4,5,6"` if the values are `[1,2,3,4,5,6]`. Also, it only stores 1 dimension (higher dimensional arrays are flattened).

Comment: This is sending me down a long rabbit hole.  I'd have to believe it can read 2D text files like the ones saved using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file.

Comment: From a quick glance, it seems like they're using `savetxt` and `loadtxt` (instead of `fromfile`)... Maybe that's the source of your confusion (?)