# Read npy data file in Python and export as text file

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

I have an array saved in a npy file and want to export it into readable text columns.

The array is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1DErx4e0NBJJNxixMSuGQaahdAcGX7jkI

I did the following:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.load('D:/20190805_01_data.npy')
```

`type(data`) gives `numpy.ndarray`

`len(data)` gives `1363`

`data.ndim` gives `3`

To export data I tried:

```
np.savetxt('D:/data.txt',data, delimiter=' ')
```

which does not work.

What is the correct solution?

Comment: what is the output op np.savetxt?

Comment: I looked here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html. The output should be a text file containing columns.

Comment: Sorry I was unclear. I do not mean to ask what the output is *supposed* to be, rather I wish to ask what *your current output* is.

Comment: How do you want to represent 3d (`data.ndim = 3`) data in a simple text file? There are only two dimensions (rows and columns). The `function np.savetxt`supports only 1d or 2d data according to the documentation.

Comment: @MofX: I thought there are 1363 lines with 2 coumns, when I check e.g. `data[1::5]`.

Comment: @lio `data.ndim` == 3 means that you have a 3-dimensional array. You can check this post on how to write multidimensional data into a txt file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file

Comment: 1363 lines with 2 columns would be a two dimensional array -> `ndim = 2`. I did not look at your source file, because I don't really like downloading and evaluating it.

Comment: @MofX: Where should I upload the file, so that somebody can check it?

Comment: You should have told us the `shape` initially.  It would have saved a lot of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems that your data have one extra dimension

```
data.shape
Out[4]: (1363, 1, 2)
```

You can do the following to remove this dimension :

```
data = np.squeeze(data)
```

and then save `data` to a .txt file.

Comment: How should the `save`look like?

Comment: Ah I have it: `np.savetxt('D:/data.txt', data, fmt=('%12.8f %12.8f'))`

Comment: Yes but I think you could keep the save function  from your first code. It worked for me