# Python - OpenCv Camera Calibration - Saving map matrix to file and read them back

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to store into a txt file the result of my camera calibration intended as mapx and mapy retrived from the following script:

```
mapx, mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx, dist, None, newcameramtx, (w, h), cv2.CV_16SC2)
```

Those are two matrix with respective shape: `(480, 640, 2)` and `(480, 640)`

The save function is working properly and it is the following one:

```
def write(filename, data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
        outfile.write('# Array shape: {0}\n'.format(data.shape))

        for data_slice in data:
            np.savetxt(outfile, data_slice, fmt='%-7.0f')
            outfile.write('# New slice\n')
```

Once the file is stored appears like this (mapy example):

```
# Array shape: (480, 640)
372    
170    
992    
823    
621    
452    
282    
113    
935
....
86     
193    
# New slice
274    
203    
131    
92     
21     
1006   
935
....
```

I'm reading it back with this function:

```
shapex = (480, 640, 2)
shapey = (480, 640)

file_mapx = "mapx.txt"
file_mapy = "mapy.txt"

mapx = np.loadtxt(file_mapx) if os.path.exists(file_mapx) else None
mapy = np.loadtxt(file_mapy) if os.path.exists(file_mapy) else None  


if mapx is not None:
    print("Reshape mapx")
    mapx = mapx.reshape(shapex)
if mapy is not None:
    print("Reshape mapy")
    mapy = mapy.reshape(shapey)
```

Everything seams working correctly but when I use those maps for the undistortion function

```
# undistort
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

I get the following error:

```
undistorted_img = cv2.remap(img, mapx, mapy, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /home/myuser/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/imgwarp.cpp:1815: error: (-215:Assertion failed) ((map1.type() == CV_32FC2 || map1.type() == CV_16SC2) && map2.empty()) || (map1.type() == CV_32FC1 && map2.type() == CV_32FC1) in function 'remap'
```

I tried following the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685265/how-to-write-a-multidimensional-array-to-a-text-file) but I didn't manage to understand the mistake, any help?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, your input to remap needs to have correct type. When you are using `CV_16SC2`, the corresponding numpy type is `np.int16`. Assuming all the values are read correctly, you can use `mapx.astype(np.int16)` and `mapy.astype(np.int16)` to convert the arrays.

You should consider saving the camera matrix instead of transformation maps. It will be useful if you want to use different options with `initUndistortRectifyMap()` later (for example if you decide to change the image resolution) or want to calculate something else which requires knowing the intrinsic parameters. Camera matrices are also a lot smaller than the transformation maps.

Comment: Thank you. I'm saving the transformation maps cause I need a really fast rectification of the images and the remap function only is fast enough but not combined with the initUndistortRectifyMap which will cause lack on performance.