# Numpy & Pandas: Return histogram values from pandas histogram plot?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib

I know that I can plot histogram by pandas:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randn(1000) + 1})
df4['a'].hist()
```

[image]

But how can I retrieve the histogram count from such a plot?

I know I can do it by (from [Histogram values of a Pandas Series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129618/histogram-values-of-a-pandas-series))

```
count,division = np.histogram(df4['a'])
```

But get the count value after `df.hist()` using this feels very redundent. Is it possible to get the frequency value directly from pandas?

Answer (score 26):

The quick answer is:

```
pd.cut(df4['a'], 10).value_counts().sort_index()
```

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

> ```
> bins: integer, default 10
> Number of histogram bins to be used
> ```

So look at `pd.cut(df4['a'], 10).value_counts()`

You see that the values are the same as from `np.histogram`

Comment: @cqcn1991 I get that you prefer numpy.  But did this answer your question?

Comment: Sort of. I think it would be great if we can do something like `count, division = df4['a'].hist()`. This can be more convenient and require no additional code.

Comment: And how does one index the resulting values? which  is the domain and the range?

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to calculate a histogram in pandas. It is more complicated but IMO better since you avoid the weird stringed-bins that `pd.cut` returns that wreck any plot. You will also get style points for using `.pipe()`:

```
(df['a']
 .pipe(lambda s: pd.Series(np.histogram(s, range=(0, 100), bins=20)))
 .pipe(lambda s: pd.Series(s[0], index=s[1][:-1]))
)
```

You can then pipe on more things at the end, like:

```
.pipe(lambda s: s/s.sum())
```

which will give you a distribution.

Ideally, there'd be a sensible `density` in `pd.hist` that could do this for you. `Pandas` does have a `density=False` keyword but it's nonsensical. I've read explanations a thousand times, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17877159/2056246), but I've never understood it nor understood who would actually *use* it. 99.9% of the time when you see fractions on a histogram, you think "distribution", not `np.sum(pdf * np.diff(bins))` which is what `density=True` actually calculates. Makes you want to weep.