# Stacked bar plots with some missing values and many indices

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, data-visualization

I have a mass DataFrame `df` (sorted by `'year'`):

```
year       gender
1894       male
1895       male
1895       male
1896       male
1900       male
...
2008       male
2008       female
2009       male
2009       female
2009       female
```

and I aim to make a stacked bar chart with the x-axis `'year'` and the y-axis the number of occurrences of those year values, with `['gender'] == 'female'` on top of `['gender'] == 'male'` on each bar.

I tried the following:

```
import plotly.express as px

df['freq'] = df.groupby('year')['gender'].transform('count')

fig = px.bar(df, x="year", y="freq", color='gender')
fig.show()
```

However, this takes up too much runtime and returns a blank graph. So, instead of creating a stacked bar chart using `plotly`, I attempted utilizing `matplotlib`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_male = df[df['gender'] == 'male']
df_female = df[df['gender'] == 'female']

X = range(1894, 2010)

plt.bar(X, df_male['year'], color = 'b')
plt.bar(X, df_female['year'], color = 'r', bottom = df_male['year'])
plt.show()
```

But this returns `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`, which I wonder if this is due to the fact that there are some years between 1894 and 2009 in `df` that do not exist (e.g. 1897, 1898, 1899, etc.).

Any insights to help me go further would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the size of `df_male` and `df_female`?

Comment: @user_na that could be it. They are very uneven: `df_male` has a length of approximately 485,000, where `df_female` has about 45,000. But wouldn't there be a way to stack them nonetheless by their frequencies per year?

Comment: It seems that you are missing the step to create a histogram by year in the filtered arrays. You will need a histogram of the year column of those two. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129618/histogram-values-of-a-pandas-series

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution would be seaborn 0.11's `histplot`:

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'year': np.random.randint(1894, 2010, 200),
                   'gender': np.random.choice(['male', 'female'], 200)})
sns.histplot(data=df, x='year', hue='gender', discrete=True, multiple='stack')
```

[image: sns.histplot]

Another option would be to create the grouped dataframe as follows and then use pandas' plotting:

```py
df.groupby(['year', 'gender']).size().unstack().plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image: pandas plot of grouped dataframe]

Here `df.groupby(['year', 'gender']).size()` creates a series using year and gender as index.  `unstack()` converts the gender index to a dataframe with two columns. The unstacked dataframe could also be sent to plotly. It looks like:

```py
gender  female  male
year                
1894       1.0   3.0
1895       1.0   4.0
1896       NaN   1.0
1897       NaN   2.0
....
```