# binning a dataframe in pandas in Python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Given the following dataframe in pandas:

```
import numpy as np
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100), "b": np.random.random(100), "id": np.arange(100)})
```

where `id` is an id for each point consisting of an `a` and `b` value, how can I bin `a` and `b` into a specified set of bins (so that I can then take the median/average value of `a` and `b` in each bin)? `df` might have `NaN` values for `a` or `b` (or both) for any given row in `df`.

Here's a better example using Joe Kington's solution with a more realistic `df`. The thing I'm unsure about is how to access the `df.b` elements for each `df.a` group below:

```
a = np.random.random(20)
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": a, "b": a + 10})
# bins for df.a
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
# bin df according to a
groups = df.groupby(np.digitize(df.a,bins))
# Get the mean of a in each group
print groups.mean()
## But how to get the mean of b for each group of a?
# ...
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way (I have a feeling `pandas.crosstab` would be useful here), but here's how I'd do it:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100),
                       "b": np.random.random(100),
                       "id": np.arange(100)})

# Bin the data frame by "a" with 10 bins...
bins = np.linspace(df.a.min(), df.a.max(), 10)
groups = df.groupby(np.digitize(df.a, bins))

# Get the mean of each bin:
print groups.mean() # Also could do "groups.aggregate(np.mean)"

# Similarly, the median:
print groups.median()

# Apply some arbitrary function to aggregate binned data
print groups.aggregate(lambda x: np.mean(x[x > 0.5]))
```

---

Edit: As the OP was asking specifically for just the means of `b` binned by the values in `a`, just do

```
groups.mean().b
```

Also if you wanted the index to look nicer (e.g. display intervals as the index), as they do in @bdiamante's example, use `pandas.cut` instead of `numpy.digitize`.  (Kudos to bidamante. I didn't realize `pandas.cut` existed.)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100), 
                       "b": np.random.random(100) + 10})

# Bin the data frame by "a" with 10 bins...
bins = np.linspace(df.a.min(), df.a.max(), 10)
groups = df.groupby(pandas.cut(df.a, bins))

# Get the mean of b, binned by the values in a
print groups.mean().b
```

This results in:

```
a
(0.00186, 0.111]    10.421839
(0.111, 0.22]       10.427540
(0.22, 0.33]        10.538932
(0.33, 0.439]       10.445085
(0.439, 0.548]      10.313612
(0.548, 0.658]      10.319387
(0.658, 0.767]      10.367444
(0.767, 0.876]      10.469655
(0.876, 0.986]      10.571008
Name: b
```

Comment: excellent and elegant! exactly what I was looking for. does not require sorting of the dataframe at all.

Comment: what if you wanted to access the `b` values based on the groups? `groups.mean()` gives you the means for just `a`, I believe.

Comment: @user248237dfsf - No, it gives the mean for both `a` and `b` (or rather, it gives the mean of `b` binned by the values in `a`, which is what I thought you were asking for).

Comment: `groups.mean()` returns a `DataFrame` so you could do `groups.mean()["b"]` to access just the means for `b` binned by `a`.

Answer (score 27):

Not 100% sure if this is what you're looking for, but here's what I think you're getting at:

```
In [144]: df = DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100), "b": np.random.random(100), "id":   np.arange(100)})

In [145]: bins = [0, .25, .5, .75, 1]

In [146]: a_bins = df.a.groupby(cut(df.a,bins))

In [147]: b_bins = df.b.groupby(cut(df.b,bins))

In [148]: a_bins.agg([mean,median])
Out[148]:
                 mean    median
a
(0, 0.25]    0.124173  0.114613
(0.25, 0.5]  0.367703  0.358866
(0.5, 0.75]  0.624251  0.626730
(0.75, 1]    0.875395  0.869843

In [149]: b_bins.agg([mean,median])
Out[149]:
                 mean    median
b
(0, 0.25]    0.147936  0.166900
(0.25, 0.5]  0.394918  0.386729
(0.5, 0.75]  0.636111  0.655247
(0.75, 1]    0.851227  0.838805
```

Of course, I don't know what bins you had in mind, so you'll have to swap mine out for your circumstance.

Comment: Nice! I assumed the OP wanted to bin "b" by "a", but in retrospect, your answer is probably what they were looking for. I'll leave mine up, as our answers do slightly different things.

Comment: Maybe worth to mention that it is `pandas.Dataframe({..})` and `a_bins.agg([numpy.mean,numpy.median])`

Answer (score 17):

Joe Kington's answer was very helpful, however, I noticed that it does not bin all of the data. It actually leaves out the row with a = a.min(). Summing up `groups.size()` gave 99 instead of 100.

To guarantee that all data is binned, just pass in the number of bins to cut() and that function will automatically pad the first[last] bin by 0.1% to ensure all data is included.

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({"a": np.random.random(100), 
                    "b": np.random.random(100) + 10})

# Bin the data frame by "a" with 10 bins...
groups = df.groupby(pandas.cut(df.a, 10))

# Get the mean of b, binned by the values in a
print(groups.mean().b)
```

In this case, summing up groups.size() gave 100.

I know this is a picky point for this particular problem, but for a similar problem I was trying to solve, it was crucial to obtain the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not have to stick to `pandas` grouping, you could use `scipy.stats.binned_statistic`:

```
from scipy.stats import binned_statistic

means = binned_statistic(df.a, df.b, bins=np.linspace(min(df.a), max(df.a), 10))
```