# Python: draw scatter with marker size coming from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Say I have a regular grid of `nxn` points, and a dictionary telling me how many times something happens in each one of the points:

```
d={
 (0, 0): 1114,
 (0, 1): 270,
 (3, 2): 217,
 (5, 6): 189,
 (10, 10): 164}
```

I want to plot a scatter of these points, the size of the markers being assigned by the corresponding value of the dict. **How can I do this?**

I know I can draw a scatter like this, but how to structure `s`, the list of sizes?

```
#Import section
#defining d
xticks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
yticks = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
plt.xticks(xticks)
plt.yticks(yticks)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y",rotation=0)
plt.title('my map')
s=[] #How to structure this?
plt.scatter(x, y,color='yellow',s=s)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`X` `Y` and `S` are all parallel lists, so for every `x[n]` will corrospond to `y[n]` and `s[n]`. You can just iterate over the dictionary and append to all three lists simultaneously:

```
x_arr,y_arr,s_arr = [], [], []
for (x,y),s in d.items():
    x_arr.append(x)
    y_arr.append(y)
    s_arr.append(s)
plt.scatter(x_arr, y_arr,color='yellow',s=s_arr)
```

There are probably more efficient ways of accomplishing this but this demonstrates how the input should be structured.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, is it possible one (or a few) are so large it/they cover up most of the other data points? maybe you need to add a division to the `s` values to handle extreme values.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks. I should have assigned `x_arr` and `y_arr` as arguments.

Comment: ah yes, that was my fault for changing the variable names on you, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Is there any appropriate legend for this kind of plot? Referring to the size of the marker maybe?

Comment: Sorry, my knowledge in matplotlib is extremely limited, I think [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36852302/5827215) would probably suite you though.