# Matplotlib Scatterplot Point Size Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

Below is a small amount of code that produces the attached image using matplotlib's scatterplot. [image: Output image from code.]

I'm trying to get a "legend" that that shows the size of several points and the corresponding "z-value".

Short of building it myself, is there anything like this?  A "size" analogy to the colorbar?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
inset = fig.add_subplot(111)

np.random.seed(0) # so the image is reproducible
x1 = np.random.rand(30)
y1 = np.random.rand(30)
z1 = np.random.rand(30)


axis = inset.scatter(x1,y1,s=z1*100,c=z1,vmin=0,vmax=1)

inset.set_xlabel("X axis")
inset.set_ylabel("Y axis")

cbar = fig.colorbar(axis,ticks=[0,0.5,1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["Low","Medium","High"])

plt.savefig('scatterplot-zscale.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To you get a legend, you need to pass the keyword `label` when calling `scatter` on at least one data point.  One way to do it is to select 3 representative points from your data, and add them to the plot again with labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0) # so the image is reproducible
x1 = np.random.rand(30)
y1 = np.random.rand(30)
z1 = np.random.rand(30)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
inset = fig.add_subplot(111)
# i prefer no outlines on the dots, so edgecolors='none'
axis = inset.scatter(x1,y1,s=z1*100,c=z1,vmin=0,vmax=1,edgecolors='none')

inset.set_xlabel("X axis")
inset.set_ylabel("Y axis")

cbar = fig.colorbar(axis,ticks=[0,0.5,1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["Low","Medium","High"])

# here we step over the sorted data into 4 or 5 strides and select the 
# last 3 steps as a representative sample, this only works if your 
# data is fairly uniformly distributed
legend_sizes = np.sort(z1)[::len(z1)//4][-3:]

# get the indices for each of the legend sizes
indices = [np.where(z1==v)[0][0] for v in legend_sizes]

# plot each point again, and its value as a label
for i in indices:
    inset.scatter(x1[i],y1[i],s=100*z1[i],c=z1[i], vmin=0,vmax=1,edgecolors='none',
                  label='{:.2f}'.format(z1[i]))
# add the legend
inset.legend(scatterpoints=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A more recent answer on Stackoverflow provides a simpler solution. [creating a matplotlib scatter legend size related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24164797/creating-a-matplotlib-scatter-legend-size-related)

> Use .legend_elements("sizes"):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
inset = fig.add_subplot(111)

np.random.seed(0) # so the image is reproducible
x1 = np.random.rand(30)
y1 = np.random.rand(30)
z1 = np.random.rand(30)


axis = inset.scatter(x1,y1,s=z1*100,c=z1,vmin=0,vmax=1)

inset.set_xlabel("X axis")
inset.set_ylabel("Y axis")

cbar = fig.colorbar(axis,ticks=[0,0.5,1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["Low","Medium","High"])

plt.legend(*axis.legend_elements("sizes", num=5), loc = 'upper right')

plt.savefig('scatterplot-zscale.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

[Figure with size legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAIxE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above create size legends that are aesthetically inconsistent with the colorbar.

To present size information in the same format as the colorbar you can create a new axis beside the colorbar axis and plot some example markers on that axis, as shown below.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
inset = fig.add_subplot(111)

np.random.seed(0) # so the image is reproducible
x1 = np.random.rand(30)
y1 = np.random.rand(30)
z1 = np.random.rand(30)


axis = inset.scatter(x1,y1,s=z1*100,c=z1,vmin=0,vmax=1)

inset.set_xlabel("X axis")
inset.set_ylabel("Y axis")

cbar = fig.colorbar(axis,ticks=[0,0.5,1])
cbar.ax.set_yticklabels(["Low","Medium","High"])

legend_values = np.sort(z1)[::len(z1)//4][-3:]

# get the indices for each of the legend sizes
indices = [np.where(z1==v)[0][0] for v in legend_values]

# Create new axis to record size legend

# Get bounds of colorbar axis
xmin, ymin, dx, dy = cbar.ax.get_position().bounds

# Create new axis that is shorter but hase same width and aligns with the top of the colourbar axis
xmin = xmin+0.11
ymin = ymin+dy - dy/3
dx = dx
dy = dy/3
sax = fig.add_axes([xmin, ymin, dx, dy])

# Plot legend size entries onto this axis
x = [0]*len(legend_values)
y = range(len(legend_values))
sizes = legend_values*100
sax.scatter(x, y, s = sizes, c = 'black', edgecolors = 'none', marker = 'o')

# Add y axis labels and remove x ticks
sax.yaxis.set_label_position("right")
sax.yaxis.tick_right()
sax.set_yticks(y)
sax.set_yticklabels(np.round_(legend_values, decimals=1), fontdict = {'size':11})
sax.set_ylabel('Z', rotation=0, labelpad = 10, fontdict = {'size':11})
sax.set_xticks([])

# remove spines
for pos in ['right', 'top', 'bottom', 'left']:
    sax.spines[pos].set_visible(False)

plt.savefig('scatterplot-zscale.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

[Figure with colorbar and 'sizebar'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dseuv.png)