# creating a scatter legend size with range 0-100 no matter what the range of the data

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, scatter-plot

I am having trouble with creating a matplotlib scatter plot with a legend showing the size diameter of points. The problem is with the scatter_plot.legend_elements function.

The problem is I want to create a legend with points representing values between [0,25,50,75,100]
But based on the [legend elements function documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PathCollection.legend_elements) it makes the legend values in a normed range.  How to make the num range between 0-100 no matter the range of Percentage variable?

I appreciate the help

```
import sys
def make_scatter_plot_by_tissue(df, size_legend="auto"):
    
    #sort df by Percentage
    df=df.sort_values(by=['Percentage'], ascending=False)

    genes = df.Genes.unique()
  
        
    if len(genes) > 1:
        sys.stderr.write("check there is only one gene\n")
    else:
        gene = genes[0]
        
    plt.figure(figsize = (20,20))
    scatter_plot = plt.scatter(df['Genes'], df['Groups'],
                            s=df['Percentage'], c=df['Average rank'], # size of points based on percentage
                            cmap='Reds', alpha=0.7)

                           


    # Add a colorbar to show the mapping of colors to values
    cbar = plt.colorbar(scatter_plot)
    cbar.set_label('Average Rank', fontsize=20)
     
    #set the cbar legend range to be 0-5000
    plt.clim(0, 5000)
    #set the cbar label font size
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)
    


    # code based on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58485655/1735942
    # Create a custom legend with circles representing the dot sizes
    # how to make the num range between 0-100 no matter the range of Percentage variable?
    size_legend = plt.legend(*scatter_plot.legend_elements(prop="sizes", num="auto"), 
                         loc='center left', title='Percentage', bbox_to_anchor=(1.30, .5), fontsize=15)
    
    
    #add grid lines to scatter_plot4


    # Set the title for the size legend
    size_legend.set_title('Percentage')
    size_legend.get_title().set_fontsize('20')
    

    # Display the plot
    #decrease the font size on y axis
    plt.yticks(fontsize=15)
    plt.xticks(fontsize=15, rotation=90)
    #set the xlabel font size
    plt.xlabel('Genes', fontsize=20)
    #set the ylabel font size
    plt.ylabel('Tissue type', fontsize=20)
  
    title_string=f"Tissue expression summmary {gene}"
    plt.title(title_string, fontsize=20)
    plt.show()
```

[image: I want to make the Percentage legend show point sizes between 0-100, depsite the actual ranges of Percentage in the data being only between 0-15]

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a dummy invisible scatterplot to create the legend from:

```py
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
scatter = ax.scatter([1, 4, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7, 8], sizes=[70, 20, 30, 80])

legend_scatter = ax.scatter(
    [5, 5, 5, 5], [5, 5, 5, 5], sizes=[25, 50, 75, 100], visible=False
)
legend_elements = legend_scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes")

ax.legend(*legend_elements)
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

You can also create a [completely custom legend](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html).