# Changing pandas group column throws warning

Tags: python, pandas

In the following piece of code, I group the points of a DataFrame by their X value into *bins*. Now I want to assign a group ID to the Y column, but pandas keep throwing me a warning of type `SettingWithCopyWarning`. What am I doing wrong?

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
d = np.random.random((10, 2))
d[:, 1] = 0
m = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=("x", "gid"))
dx = 0.2
grp = m.groupby(lambda i: int(m["x"][i] / dx))
gid = 1
for name, group in grp:
    group["gid"][:] = gid # This line crashes!
    gid += 1
print(m)
```

Here is the warning thrown:

```
/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:677: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._set_with(key, value)
sys:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16949498/1571826 for a more elegant and flexible approach to binning.

Comment: What version pandas are you using?  I'm also running python 3.4 and I didn't get any warning when I ran your code exactly as is.

Comment: Works fine in python 3.4.3, pandas 0.16.1 and numpy 1.9.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here. First, you are getting a `SettingWithCopyWarning` because

```
group["gid"][:] = gid
```

uses "chained-indexing". The problem is that sometimes `group[...]` may return a *copy* instead of a *view* of `group`, and so further indexing and modification of the copy, e.g. `group[...][...] = gid` [may be useless since it only modifies the copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) and not `group`. `SettingWithCopyWarning` is a *warning* that chained-indexing has been detected in an assignment. It does not necessarily mean anything has gone wrong. In your case `group["gid"]` returns a view of `group`, so your chained indexing happens to succeed in modifying `group` itself.

Nevertheless, the recommended practice is to *always* avoid chained-indexing when performing assignments since it is not always easy to predict if the chained-indexing will return a view or a copy.

Usually you can avoid chained-indexing by using `.loc` or `iloc`:

```
group.loc[:, "gid"] = gid
```

---

The second issue is that even if we avoid chained indexing, modifying `group` does not modify `m`.

When you use a `for-loop`:

```
for name, group in grp:
```

Python creates local variables `name` and `group` and bind these variables to items in `grp`. But these items are themselves *copies*, not *views*, of portions of `m`. So modifying these copies do not affect `m`.

---

Instead of using groupby, you could use `pd.Categorical`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
d = np.random.random((10, 2))
d[:, 1] = 0
m = pd.DataFrame(d, columns=("x", "gid"))
dx = 0.2
m['gid'] = pd.Categorical((m['x'] / dx).astype(int)).codes + 1

print(m)
```

yields

```
          x  gid
0  0.737595    3
1  0.884189    4
2  0.944676    4
3  0.063603    1
4  0.332454    2
5  0.003218    1
6  0.071058    1
7  0.289020    2
8  0.268896    2
9  0.258775    2
```