# How can I group rows in groups of 5 using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that looks like this:

[image]

And the numbers are either zero or one. I want to make a plot of this, but of course it looks crazy because values are either 0 or 1, so the lines jump around a lot. How can I group the rows by 5s or 10s, summing all the data in each group, so that I can make a more meaningful plot?

Comment: what do you want to plot?

Comment: Where in the series each of the tags occur. So it's not super meaningful that "interruptions" happens once at 0, and once at 6, but more meaninful that it happens twice in the range 0-10.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for "binning"?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16947336/binning-a-dataframe-in-pandas-in-python