# How does python matplotlib.pyplot support datatype from pandas, xarray etc.?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

To put the question in the simplest way -- how does the last line of this code work?

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
tmp = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(100,100))
howthiswork = np.array(tmp)
```

I'm under the impression that pandas is built on the top numpy [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11077215/5426033) and then xarray is sort of based on pandas [link](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/why-xarray.html#goals-and-aspirations). However, I don't find any info stating that numpy itself supports xarray.DataArray, plus not a lot of people are using xarray than numpy. So why can I initialize a numpy.ndarray with an xarray.DataArray object? One of my guess is that corresponding supporting is provided in the xarray package but **I don't see a mechanism where codes from xarray package could affect numpy.ndarray.__init__** (or whatever function from numpy package)..

Can anyone give me an explanation of how this up-down support is achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NumPy's looks for a `__array__` method for how to convert arbitrary objects to numpy array, which both pandas and xarray objects define.

This is pretty easy to implement for your own class, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np

class MyArray:
    def __array__(self, dtype=None):
        return np.arange(5)

 np.array(MyArray())
 # array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Does matplotlib.pyplot work in the similar way to support say plt.contour(tmp) ?

Comment: Yes, matplotlib calls `np.array` or a similar function such as `np.asarray` under the hood. This is considered a best practice for libraries that accept numpy arrays in function arguments.