# Read number from file and put it into two-dimensional list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. My file contains these numbers:

```
2,3
4,5
7,8
-4,3
```

How can I read this file and convert it into a two dimensional list so that I can calculate an area?

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work? Please show some effort. We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: Searching in SO for `[python] csv` get's you a lot of relevant SO questions.

Answer (score 3):

something like this:

```
>>> with open("data1.txt") as f:
...    lis=[list(map(int,x.split(","))) for x in f]
...    print lis
... 
[[2, 3], [4, 5], [7, 8], [-4, 3]]
```

Comment: The numbers were in multiple lines; the OP didn't format the text.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually parsing the file, you could also use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module to do this. A small example:

```
import csv
with open('data1.txt', 'rb') as csvfile:
  spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

twod_list = [row for row in spamreader]
```

In addition, if you want to start working with [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/) (which you want if you want to do serious calculations), take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-do-i-read-csv-data-into-a-record-array-in-numpy) for how to read your data into a `numpy` array. The following code I copied form the linked question:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
my_data = genfromtxt('data1.txt', delimiter = ',')
```