# plotting a histogram for a column in a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a histogram and a scatter plot for a particular column in a given csv file. I am new to programming and I got this code from a friend, and it apparently works but somehow I am getting this error. the code is:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
f = open('Data for question 13.csv')
data = csv.reader(f)
Area = []; MajorAxisLength = []; MinorAxisLength = []; Perimeter = []
MinIntensity = []; MeanIntensity = []; MaxIntensity = []
header = [Area, MajorAxisLength, MinorAxisLength,Perimeter,MinIntensity,MeanIntensity,MaxIntensity]
for row in data:
    i = 1 
    for name in header:
        name.append(row[i])
        i = i + 1
plt.figure()
plt.hist(Area, bins=50) # error follows after this
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    plt.hist(Area, bins=50, alpha=0.5)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2827, in hist
    stacked=stacked, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.py", line 8312, in hist
    xmin = min(xmin, xi.min())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.9.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg/numpy/core/_methods.py", line 29, in _amin
    return umr_minimum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims)
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

I am unable to get rid of this error.
The answer should be simple but since I am new I have no idea how to deal with it.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What does your data file look like?

Comment: is there a way I could share or upload the data file to look at how the data looks?
 I do not know if this would give you any idea and would help: It has 9 columns with headers and numerical data till approx 400 rows.

Comment: Either paste the first few lines into the question (only ~10), or use eg. [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and put the link in the questtion

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the input data is interpreted as string by the csv parser while hist requires numeric data. You should explicitly convert each `row[i]` before appending it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to plot some numerical data in your csv file, and that the data is numeric (not text) you could probably use the same method as mentioned here: [How to read csv into record array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy)

Thus, your code might look like this:

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.genfromtxt('Data for question 13.csv')  # add more parameter info if neccessary like skipping header lines
plt.figure()
plt.hist(data[:,0], bins=50)  # Area, from OP, is column 0
```

Info on the genfromtxt function can be found here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Comment: Hey, I tried this too but I get the error for too many indices. 
IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Then it sounds like your file might be empty. Do `print(data.shape)` (or `print data.shape` in Py2) and if it's `(0,0)` there's something wrong with your file. You could also plot it in Excel to know what you're looking for. There's enough clues in the errors you've gotten from mine and @hitzg's answers that you should be able to solve the problem. `IndexError`? The data isn't there/big enough. `ValueError`? Look at the string; what is it? Is it convertable?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, as I don't have your data file available. But I think `row[i]` is a string (and not an integer or float). And you can use `enumerate` to skip the first line.
So this should solve the problem:

```
for n,row in enumerate(data):
    if n > 0:
        i = 1 
        for name in header:
            name.append(float(row[i]))
            i = i + 1
```

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me an error: 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: Area

Comment: If the first line of your file includes the headers you have to skip it. It is extremely difficult to help you without the file that you're working with. And I think @James' answer is doing what you want more directly. You should read the documentation he linked.

Comment: I tried this again with skipping the header after reading the documentation and it did work. Thanks for the help.