# Parsing a tab separated file using python

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a file which looks like this, this a tab separated text file

```
  aaa   0.0520852296    0.1648703511    0.1648703511
  bbb   0.1062639955    0.1632039268    0.1632039268
  ccc   1.4112745088    4.3654577641    4.3654577641
  ddd   0.4992644913    0.1648703511    0.1648703511
  eeee  0.169058175 0.1632039268    0.1632039268
```

and the output should be

```
aaa 0.0232736716    0.0328321936    0.0328321936
bbb 0.0474828153    0.0325003428    0.0325003428
ccc 0.6306113983    0.8693349271    0.8693349271
ddd 0.2230904597    0.0328321936    0.0328321936
eeee    0.0755416551    0.0325003428    0.0325003428
```

That each row/total sum of column

So on with many rows and columns for this `.txt` file I need to find the column sum for each column from. 2nd column to last column and then divide each numerical row with the column sum.
And print it as the output.
So far I have done until split and strip and from there I am not able to select select from second row.

```
import numpy as np
motif_path  = '/home/test/test.txt'
f         =open(motif_path,'r') 
x = f.readlines()
kk = [s.strip().split("\t") for s in x]
```

When I tried 
`for i in Kk[1][1]`, I received and error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Obviously, the exact wording of that Error is relevant, as well as the line it refers to. Add that to your question!

Comment: Please also add your complete `for` loop, not just the first line with a comment.

Comment: also, are you sure that you did not make a copy and paste mistake `kk` is not the same as `Kk`!

Comment: And fix your syntax highlighting

Comment: Why you added the `numpy` tag? did you want a solution in `numpy`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read csv into record array in numpy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw the "numpy" tag but you might consider python's "pandas" as alternative where you get the desired output within only a few lines; this way you can easily divide each entry by the sum of its column/row.

First you read in the file as a data frame and then you do the desired operations on the three columns of this dataframe. If you wish, you can then easily write this dataframe back to a .txt file (output is shown below). Let me know whether that meets your needs and whether you have question about this code.

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
f=open('myData.txt','r')
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', header=None, names=['val1', 'val2', 'val3']))
print df
df.loc[:,"val1":"val3"] = df.loc[:,"val1":"val3"].div(df.sum(axis=0), axis=1)
print df
df.to_csv('output.txt', header=None,sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

And the output of this script would be:

```
          val1      val2      val3
aaa   0.052085  0.164870  0.164870
bbb   0.106264  0.163204  0.163204
ccc   1.411275  4.365458  4.365458
ddd   0.499264  0.164870  0.164870
eeee  0.169058  0.163204  0.163204

          val1      val2      val3
aaa   0.023274  0.032832  0.032832
bbb   0.047483  0.032500  0.032500
ccc   0.630611  0.869335  0.869335
ddd   0.223090  0.032832  0.032832
eeee  0.075542  0.032500  0.032500
```

and the file "output.txt" looks like this:

```
aaa 0.0232736716104 0.0328321936442 0.0328321936442
bbb 0.0474828152678 0.0325003427993 0.0325003427993
ccc 0.630611398322  0.869334927113  0.869334927113
ddd 0.223090459743  0.0328321936442 0.0328321936442
eeee    0.075541655057  0.0325003427993 0.0325003427993
```

Comment: I am afraid I cant see a check next to your answer also I am not able to do a vote to your since I am new user, I am sorry..:(

Comment: Along with the line I have to calculate entropy on the output data, and so I appiled the formula for that on output as, entropy = - sum([ p * math.log(p) / math.log(2.0) for p in df ])  but it throws error as, NameError: name 'math' is not defined May I know how can I get it done .?

Comment: I have added it as a new question now

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the [csv reader](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module of python and change the delimitor from a `,` to a space?

```
import csv
motif_path  = '/home/test/test.txt'
with open(motif_path, 'rb') as csvfile:
    data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    for dI in data:
        print dI
```

**Output**

```
['Aaa', '0.4567', '0.6780']
['Bibb', '0.6783', '0.235']
['Cccc', '0.4567', '0.4567']
```

Comment: Thank you Jen, for the  reply, but myfile is tab seperated file,  aaa 0.0520852296 0.1648703511 0.1648703511
bbb 0.1062639955 0.1632039268 0.1632039268
ccc 1.4112745088 4.3654577641 4.3654577641
ddd 0.4992644913 0.1648703511 0.1648703511
eeee 0.169058175 0.1632039268 0.1632039268
  and the output i need is  row of colum/ sum(column)

Comment: Then replace the space with `\t` and **please** specify requirements like this in the question. Because otherwise nobody will give you a perfectly suitable answer.

Comment: And please change the title. And your syntax highlighting.

Comment: Change the title to what?

Comment: To something that describes your question. Since you desire to get an answer to something else than *python array with string*, this is the only way to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have provided, `kk` will be `[['Aaa 0.4567 0.6780'], ['Bibb 0.6783. 0.235'], ['Cccc 0.4567. 0.4567'], ['']]`

which means `k[1][1]` will be out of bounds. What was your expected output and i might be able to help further

Comment: yes, that is the problem I need numbers alone so that I can find the sum of column , for [['Aaa 0.4567 0.6780'] I need just the numeric part so as for all rows and so then I need to find the sum of column