# Numpy is adding dot(.) from CSV data

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading CSV as:

```
import numpy as np
features = np.genfromtxt('train.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=(1,2))
```

It outputs data as:

> [[-1. -1.]  [ 1. -1.]  [-1.  1.]  [ 1. -1.]]. See the dot after `1` and `-1`

**train.csv**

```
0,-1,-1
-1,1,-1
0,-1,1
1,1,-1
-1,1,-1
0,1,-1
```

Comment: Can you show a record from `train.csv` ?

Comment: there has to be a value somewhere in there that makes numpy convert to floats.

Comment: @Jan Question updated

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I tried this and seems it worked `features = np.genfromtxt('train.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=(1,2),dtype=int)`

Comment: So, your problem is now solved? Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy. Apparently, casting to a numpy array at the end is more efficient.

Comment: @Volatil3 of course if you specify the dtype to int, the float will go away, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html#choosing-the-data-type

Comment: In the link provided by @user69453 it says: **"Note that dtype=float is the default for genfromtxt."**

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments : `np.genfromtxt` is simply converting your data to float numbers by default ([see the default dtype argument in the function signature](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)). If you want to force the output to integers just specify `dtype=np.int` in genfromtxt:

```
features = np.genfromtxt('train.csv',delimiter=',',usecols=(1,2),dtype=np.int)
```