# Load csv file in processing.py

Tags: python, csv, processing, visualization

I am trying to load a csv file in processing.py as a table. The Java environment allows me to use the loadTable() function, however, I'm unable to find an equivalent function in the python environment.

Comment: Does using the standard python library to read CSV's not work for your use-case? https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy)

Comment: Processing.py looks to have `loadTable` now: https://github.com/jdf/processing.py/blob/7c30e038600c221c5b70590a50160d918b5dd86b/mode/examples/Topics/AdvancedData/LoadSaveTable/LoadSaveTable.pyde#L44

Answer (score 0):

The missing functionality could be added as follows:

```
import csv

class Row(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_row):
        self.dict_row = dict_row

    def getFloat(self, key):
        return float(self.dict_row[key])

    def getString(self, key):
        return self.dict_row[key]

class loadTable(object):
    def __init__(self, csv_filename, header):
        with open(csv_filename, "rb") as f_input:
            csv_input = csv.DictReader(f_input)
            self.data = [Row(row) for row in csv_input]

    def rows(self):
        return self.data
```

This reads the csv file into memory using Python's [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=dictreader#csv.DictReader) class. This treats each row in the csv file as a dictionary. For each row, it creates an instance of a `Row` class which then lets you retrieve entries in the format required. Currently I have just coded for `getFloat()` and `getString()` (which is the default format for all csv values).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty `Table` object with this:

```py
from processing.data import Table
t = Table()
```

And then populate it as discussed at https://discourse.processing.org/t/creating-an-empty-table-object-in-python-mode-and-some-other-hidden-data-classes/25121

But I think a Python Dict as proposed by @martin-evans would be nice. You load it like this:

```py
import csv
from codecs import open # optional to have the 'enconding="utf-8"' in Python 2

with open("data/pokemon.csv", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    data = list(csv.DictReader(f))  # a list of dicts, col-headers as keys
```