# How to read file with mixed data type into a numpy array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, readfile, mixed

How to read file with mixed data type into a numpy array in Python?

I'm a new python learner. I'm trying to read an existing file with mixed data type into a numpy array.

The content of file data.txt (if comma is not a good symbol, it can be replaced by space):

```
   ,'A','B','C','D'
'A',  0,  3,  5, -1
'B',  3,  0,  1,  6
'C',  5,  1,  0,  2
'D', -1,  6,  2,  0
```

The expected output numpy array is as follows:

```
array([[None,'A','B','C','D'],
       ['A',  0,  3,  5, -1 ],
       ['B',  3,  0,  1,  6 ],
       ['C',  5,  1,  0,  2 ],
       ['D', -1,  6,  2,  0 ]])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read csv into record array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy)

Comment: There's no possible way to get exactly your expected output with a plain numpy array (at least not if that's a 2D array). However you could try to read it into a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', index_col=0, sep=',')
>>> print(df)
     'A'  'B'  'C'  'D'

'A'    0    3    5   -1
'B'    3    0    1    6
'C'    5    1    0    2
'D'   -1    6    2    0
```

You can then access the underlying array with `.values`:

```
>>> df.values
array([[ 0,  3,  5, -1],
       [ 3,  0,  1,  6],
       [ 5,  1,  0,  2],
       [-1,  6,  2,  0]], dtype=int64)
```

---

At least to my knowledge it's not possible to read that file into a plain (not-object) 2D array because a record array requires that any column follows the same types. While it could work for the second-last row `(str, int, int, int, int)` it couldn't work for the first row `(NoneType, str, str, str, str)`. At least with pandas you can interpret the first row and first column as indices which can have a different type.

However if you don't need the first row and column you could use [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> np.loadtxt('myfile.txt', delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=[1,2,3,4], dtype=int)
array([[ 0,  3,  5, -1],
       [ 3,  0,  1,  6],
       [ 5,  1,  0,  2],
       [-1,  6,  2,  0]])
```