# Retrieving values from a txt file of a new line delimiter

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to index each data separated by a new line break.

```
import cvs
with open('some_file.txt') as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.splitlines()
```

And I can read it as

```
print data[0]
>>> 0.00000e+00        1.39984e+23        8.08209e+22        1.34691e+23        7.94736e+07        3.54090e+21        1.61507e+04        0.00000e+00        4.36307e-01        2.53048e-02        1.17516e-03        5.58890e+03        5.06638e+00        0.00000e+00        4.53490e-02        5.94527e-01        4.49423e-01        5.40076e-02        8.84406e-01        1.44792e-05        2.13497e+04        3.38802e+06        3.38397e-04        3.66874e-01        2.09206e-01        3.59185e-01     45536941
print data[1]
>>> 1.00000e+00        1.46478e+23        8.85202e+22        1.07364e+23        5.65863e+07        3.16193e+21        3.11939e+03        0.00000e+00        9.08775e-01        2.01753e-02        9.82056e-04        7.68423e+03        8.29516e+00        0.00000e+00        1.26423e-01        1.68922e-02        9.82179e-01        4.30002e-02        1.21514e+00        2.93802e-06        2.44811e+06        4.00670e+06        2.71861e-05        3.79373e-01        2.31627e-01        2.82576e-01     48923553
print data[:2]
>>> ['        0.00000e+00        1.39984e+23        8.08209e+22        1.34691e+23        7.94736e+07        3.54090e+21        1.61507e+04        0.00000e+00        4.36307e-01        2.53048e-02        1.17516e-03        5.58890e+03        5.06638e+00        0.00000e+00        4.53490e-02        5.94527e-01        4.49423e-01        5.40076e-02        8.84406e-01        1.44792e-05        2.13497e+04        3.38802e+06        3.38397e-04        3.66874e-01        2.09206e-01        3.59185e-01     45536941', '        1.00000e+00        1.46478e+23        8.85202e+22        1.07364e+23        5.65863e+07        3.16193e+21        3.11939e+03        0.00000e+00        9.08775e-01        2.01753e-02        9.82056e-04        7.68423e+03        8.29516e+00        0.00000e+00        1.26423e-01        1.68922e-02        9.82179e-01        4.30002e-02        1.21514e+00        2.93802e-06        2.44811e+06        4.00670e+06        2.71861e-05        3.79373e-01        2.31627e-01        2.82576e-01     48923553']
```

Each indexed value has a specific quantity I am wanting to index out. For example, `data[0]` is the 1st particle along with its values and its index number is indicated by `data[0][0]`, positions x,y,z is indicated with `data[0][1]`, `data[0][2]`, and `data[0][3]` respectively, `data[0][4]` for its mass, and so on.

Similarly, you retrieve the same quantities from the 2nd particle `data[1]`, the 3rd `data[2]`, and so on through the entire list `data[:]`.

My problem is that I cannot index into each of the particle values as nicely as

```
posx = data[:][1]
posy = data[:][2]
posz = data[:][3]
...
```

or split into each column.

```
posx = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data] 
posy = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data] 
posz = [float(row.split()[1]) for row in data]
```

given in the format that it is in.

If you would like to reproduce it, I have provided a dropbox link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6f0cy4gk8x1k0rm/AADser16cMI9Xhhw3lyP7vWaa?dl=0

Comment: Once you have found an answer which works for you, please click the tick next to that answer to accept it. This lets other people with your problem know which solution worked for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read csv into record array in numpy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518778/how-to-read-csv-into-record-array-in-numpy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your existing code:

```
NiceArr = []
for item in data:
    NiceArr.append(item.split())
```

`NiceArr` will become an array containing arrays, and each inner array will contain the particle values.

You can retrieve each of the particle values the same way you are trying to use in your post.